# How to identify which OS Python is running on

Tags: python, operating-system, cross-platform, platform-agnostic

What do I need to look at to see whether I'm on Windows or Unix, etc.?

Comment: see (http://bugs.python.org/issue12326) for details!

Comment: Here's a related question: [Check linux distro name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756737/320399).

Answer (score 1265, accepted):

```
>>> import os

>>> os.name
'posix'

>>> import platform

>>> platform.system()
'Linux'

>>> platform.release()
'2.6.22-15-generic'
```

The output of [`platform.system()`](https://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.system) is as follows:

- Linux: `Linux`
- Mac: `Darwin`
- Windows: `Windows`

See: [`platform` — Access to underlying platform’s identifying data](https://docs.python.org/library/platform.html)

Comment: Why should I prefer `platform` over `sys.platform`?

Comment: @matth Slightly more consistent output. i.e. `platform.system()` returns `"Windows"` instead of `"win32"`. `sys.platform` also contains `"linux2"` on old versions of Python while it contains just `"linux"` on newer ones. `platform.system()` has always returned just `"Linux"`.

Comment: On mac os X, platform.system() always return "Darwin"? or is there other case possible?

Comment: @baptistechéné see the link in my answer where I have listed a few different ways to identify what system you are on ran on a few diferent machines: https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version

Comment: @baptistechéné, I know this has over an year since you asked, but as a comment won't hurt, I'll post it anyways :)

So, the reason behind it is because it shows the kernel name. The same way Linux (the kernel) distros have many names (Ubuntu, Arch, Fedora among others), but it'll present itself as the kernel name, Linux. Darwin (a BSD-based Kernel), has its surrounding system, the macOS. I'm pretty sure apple did release Darwin as an open source code, but there's no other distro running over Darwin that I know of.

Comment: `os.uname().sysname` is doing the same as `platform.system` ;)

Comment: @TooroSan `os.uname()` only exists for Unix systems.  The Python 3 docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html  
`Availability: recent flavors of Unix.`

Comment: Please note than under Windows Server, os.name returns "nt" -> not "Windows".

Comment: Also please note that in Cygwin, `platform.system()` returns `CYGWIN_NT-${windows_version}`. For example, on my laptop, it returns `CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19041`

Comment: On an ipad, platform.system() returns 'Darwin', which is true to a point. The python libraries were compiled on macos. However, sys.platform='ios', which more informative

Answer (score 221):

Here are the system results for [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista)!

```
>>> import os

>>> os.name
'nt'

>>> import platform

>>> platform.system()
'Windows'

>>> platform.release()
'Vista'
```

And for Windows 10:

```
>>> import os

>>> os.name
'nt'

>>> import platform

>>> platform.system()
'Windows'

>>> platform.release()
'10'
```

Comment: Windows 7: `platform.release()` `'7'`

Comment: So, yeah, I just ran `platform.release()` on my *Windows* *10*, and it definitely just gave me `'8'`. Maybe I installed python before upgrading, but really??

Comment: I'd have thought it's more likely you upgraded from Windows 8 (vs. it being a clean install) and whatever Python looks up in the registry or whatever was left behind?

Comment: The release lookup for python on Windows appears to use the Win32 api function GetVersionEx at its core. The notes at the top of this Microsoft article about that function could be relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 149):

For the record, here are the results on Mac:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.release()
'8.11.1'
```

Comment: On macOS Catalina 10.15.2, `platform.release()` returns `'19.2.0'`

Comment: `19.2.0` is the release version of Darwin that comes with Catalina 10.15.2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Release_history

Answer (score 135):

**Short Story**

Use `platform.system()`. It returns `Windows`, `Linux` or `Darwin` (for OS X).

**Long Story**

There are three ways to get the OS in Python, each with its own pro and cons:

**Method 1**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'win32'  # could be 'linux', 'linux2, 'darwin', 'freebsd8' etc
```

How this works ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b82e17e626f7b1cd98aada0b1ebb65cb9f8fb184/Python/sysmodule.c#L1478)): Internally it calls OS APIs to get the name of the OS as defined by the OS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874620/207661) for various OS-specific values.

Pro: No magic, low level.

Con: OS version dependent, so best not to use directly.

**Method 2**

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'nt'  # for Linux and Mac it prints 'posix'
```

How this works ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/os.py#L48)): Internally it checks if Python has OS-specific modules called *posix* or *nt*.

Pro: Simple to check if it is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) OS

Con: no differentiation between Linux or OS X.

**Method 3**

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows' # For Linux it prints 'Linux'. For Mac, it prints `'Darwin'
```

How this works ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/platform.py#L949)): Internally it will eventually call internal OS APIs, get the OS version-specific name, like 'win32' or 'win16' or 'linux1' and then normalize to more generic names like 'Windows' or 'Linux' or 'Darwin' by applying several heuristics.

Pro: The best portable way for Windows, OS X, and Linux.

Con: Python folks must keep normalization heuristic up to date.

**Summary**

- If you want to check if OS is Windows or Linux, or OS X, then the most reliable way is `platform.system()`.
- If you want to make OS-specific calls, but via built-in Python modules `posix` or `nt`, then use `os.name`.
- If you want to get the raw OS name as supplied by the OS itself, then use `sys.platform`.

Comment: So much for "There should be one (and preferably only one) way to do things".  However I believe this is the right answer.  You would need to compare with titled OS names but it's not such an issue and will be more portable.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.10 , `platform.system` defaults to `sys.platform` if the `os.uname` throws an exception:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a6c3f6d34792c5f9dc296ce8329938b7b2b02ea9/Lib/platform.py#L830-L833

Answer (score 118):

Sample code to differentiate operating systems using Python:

```
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith("linux"):  # could be "linux", "linux2", "linux3", ...
    # linux
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
elif os.name == "nt":
    # Windows, Cygwin, etc. (either 32-bit or 64-bit)
```

Comment: For fuzzier results, ``_platform.startswith('linux')

Comment: `sys.platform == 'cygwin'` on Windows Cygwin shell

Comment: Little problem: `win64` does not exis: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/platform.py. All Windows versions are `win32`.

Comment: in my windows64  sys.platform return win32

Answer (score 63):

I started a bit more systematic listing of what values you can expect using the various modules:

## Linux (64 bit) + [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

```
                            x86_64            aarch64
                            ------            -------
os.name                     posix             posix
sys.platform                linux             linux
platform.system()           Linux             Linux
sysconfig.get_platform()    linux-x86_64      linux-aarch64
platform.machine()          x86_64            aarch64
platform.architecture()     ('64bit', '')     ('64bit', 'ELF')
```

- I tried with [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) and [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint), but I got the same results
- on Python 2, `sys.platform` is suffixed by the kernel version, e.g., `linux2`, and everything else stays identical
- the same output on [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (I tried with [Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS), except `platform.architecture() = ('64bit', 'ELF')`

## Windows (64 bit)

(with 32-bit column running in the 32-bit subsystem)

```
Official Python installer   64 bit                    32 bit
-------------------------   -----                     -----
os.name                     nt                        nt
sys.platform                win32                     win32
platform.system()           Windows                   Windows
sysconfig.get_platform()    win-amd64                 win32
platform.machine()          AMD64                     AMD64
platform.architecture()     ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')    ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

msys2                       64 bit                     32 bit
-----                       -----                     -----
os.name                     posix                     posix
sys.platform                msys                      msys
platform.system()           MSYS_NT-10.0              MSYS_NT-10.0-WOW
sysconfig.get_platform()    msys-2.11.2-x86_64        msys-2.11.2-i686
platform.machine()          x86_64                    i686
platform.architecture()     ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')    ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

msys2                       mingw-w64-x86_64-python3  mingw-w64-i686-python3
-----                       ------------------------  ----------------------
os.name                     nt                        nt
sys.platform                win32                     win32
platform.system()           Windows                   Windows
sysconfig.get_platform()    mingw                     mingw
platform.machine()          AMD64                     AMD64
platform.architecture()     ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')    ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

Cygwin                      64 bit                    32 bit
------                      -----                     -----
os.name                     posix                     posix
sys.platform                cygwin                    cygwin
platform.system()           CYGWIN_NT-10.0            CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW
sysconfig.get_platform()    cygwin-3.0.1-x86_64       cygwin-3.0.1-i686
platform.machine()          x86_64                    i686
platform.architecture()     ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')    ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Some remarks:

- there is also `distutils.util.get_platform()` which is identical to `sysconfig.get_platform
- [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) on Windows is the same as the official Python Windows installer
- I don't have a Mac nor a true 32-bit system and was not motivated to do it online

To compare with your system, simply run this script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import platform
import sysconfig

print("os.name                      ",  os.name)
print("sys.platform                 ",  sys.platform)
print("platform.system()            ",  platform.system())
print("sysconfig.get_platform()     ",  sysconfig.get_platform())
print("platform.machine()           ",  platform.machine())
print("platform.architecture()      ",  platform.architecture())
```

Comment: On latest MSYS2, MinGW64 reports `sys.platform` as `win32` like your reported, but MSYS2 and UCRT64 report `cygwin` but not `msys`.

Answer (score 44):

You can also use [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) if you already have imported `sys` and you don't want to import another module

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'linux2'
```

Comment: Does on of the approaches have any advantages, besides having to or not to import another module?

Comment: Scoping is the main advantage. You want as few global variable names  as possible. When you already have "sys" as a global name, you shouldn't add another one. But if you don't use "sys" yet, using "_platform" might be more descriptive and less likely to collide with another meaning.

Answer (score 43):

If you want user readable data, but still detailed, you can use [platform.platform()](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.platform):

```py
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-3.3.0-8.fc16.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-16-Verne'
```

Here are a few different possible calls you can make to identify where you are. *linux_distribution* and *dist* are removed in recent Python versions.

```
import platform
import sys

def linux_distribution():
  try:
    return platform.linux_distribution()
  except:
    return "N/A"

def dist():
  try:
    return platform.dist()
  except:
    return "N/A"

print("""Python version: %s
dist: %s
linux_distribution: %s
system: %s
machine: %s
platform: %s
uname: %s
version: %s
mac_ver: %s
""" % (
sys.version.split('\n'),
str(dist()),
linux_distribution(),
platform.system(),
platform.machine(),
platform.platform(),
platform.uname(),
platform.version(),
platform.mac_ver(),
))
```

The outputs of this script ran on a few different systems (Linux, Windows, Solaris, and macOS) and architectures (x86, x64, [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium), [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC), and [SPARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC)) is available at *[OS_flavor_name_version](https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version)*.

[Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) server (Precise Pangolin), for example, gives:

```py
Python version: ['2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36) ', '[GCC 4.4.3]']
dist: ('Ubuntu', '10.04', 'lucid')
linux_distribution: ('Ubuntu', '10.04', 'lucid')
system: Linux
machine: x86_64
platform: Linux-2.6.32-32-server-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-10.04-lucid
uname: ('Linux', 'xxx', '2.6.32-32-server', '#62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 22:07:43 UTC 2011', 'x86_64', '')
version: #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 22:07:43 UTC 2011
mac_ver: ('', ('', '', ''), '')
```

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: dist() and linux_distribution() functions are deprecated in Python 3.5`

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
import psutil

psutil.MACOS   # True ("OSX" is deprecated)
psutil.WINDOWS # False
psutil.LINUX   # False
```

This would be the output if I was using macOS.

Comment: psutil is not part of standard lib

Answer (score 16):

Use [platform.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system)

> Returns the system/OS name, such as 'Linux', 'Darwin', 'Java', 'Windows'. An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.

```
import platform
system = platform.system().lower()

is_windows = system == 'windows'
is_linux = system == 'linux'
is_mac = system == 'darwin'
```

Comment: How can I get the name of my distro? For example, if I'm running Arch, how can I get `Arch`?

Answer (score 13):

I am using the WLST tool that comes with [WebLogic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server), and it doesn't implement the platform package.

```
wls:/offline> import os
wls:/offline> print os.name
java
wls:/offline> import sys
wls:/offline> print sys.platform
'java1.5.0_11'
```

Apart from patching the system *javaos.py* ([issue with os.system() on Windows Server 2003 with JDK 1.5](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.jython.devel/2006-08/msg00035.html)) (which I can't do, I have to use WebLogic out of the box), this is what I use:

```
def iswindows():
  os = java.lang.System.getProperty( "os.name" )
  return "win" in os.lower()
```

Answer (score 9):

For [Jython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython) the only way to get the OS name I found is to check the `os.name` Java property (I tried with `sys`, `os` and `platform` modules for Jython 2.5.3 on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP)):

```
def get_os_platform():
    """return platform name, but for Jython it uses os.name Java property"""
    ver = sys.platform.lower()
    if ver.startswith('java'):
        import java.lang
        ver = java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name").lower()
    print('platform: %s' % (ver))
    return ver
```

Comment: You can also call "platform.java_ver()" to extract OS information in Jython.

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

def cls():
    from subprocess import call
    from platform import system

    os = system()
    if os == 'Linux':
        call('clear', shell = True)
    elif os == 'Windows':
        call('cls', shell = True)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Good answer, maybe even on par with the original answer.  But you could explain why.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting results on [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'nt'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> platform.release()
'post2008Server'
```

That's [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue16176).

Answer (score 8):

Watch out if you're on Windows with Cygwin where `os.name` is `posix`.

```
>>> import os, platform
>>> print os.name
posix
>>> print platform.system()
CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW
```

Comment: Why watch out? Can you elaborate? Preferably in the answer. (But ********* ********* ********* ***WITHOUT*** ********* ********* ********* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

Here is an easy and simple-to-understand Pythonic way to detect the OS in code. It was tested on Python 3.7.

```
from sys import platform

class UnsupportedPlatform(Exception):
    pass

if "linux" in platform:
    print("linux")
elif "darwin" in platform:
    print("mac")
elif "win" in platform:
    print("windows")
else:
    raise UnsupportedPlatform
```

Comment: If this code is ever refactored by someone not understanding the structure of the if, this could lead to a false detection of macos because `win` is included in `darwin`. A `startswidth` would be less problematic.

Comment: If you are refactoring code and you haven't mastered If statements you probably have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: If possible, changing an if branch should not lead to a false positive. This concept is called clean code.

Answer (score 6):

If you not looking for the kernel version, etc., but looking for the Linux distribution, you may want to use the following.

In Python 2.6 and later:

```
>>> import platform

>>> print platform.linux_distribution()
('CentOS Linux', '6.0', 'Final')

>>> print platform.linux_distribution()[0]
CentOS Linux

>>> print platform.linux_distribution()[1]
6.0
```

In Python 2.4:

```
>>> import platform

>>> print platform.dist()
('centos', '6.0', 'Final')

>>> print platform.dist()[0]
centos

>>> print platform.dist()[1]
6.0
```

Obviously, this will work only if you are running this on Linux. If you want to have a more generic script across platforms, you can mix this with code samples given in other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import os

os.uname()
```

And you can make it:

```
info = os.uname()
info[0]
info[1]
```

Comment: Also `os.uname()` is not available on windows:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.uname _Availability: **recent flavors of Unix.**_

Answer (score 5):

You can also use only the *platform* module without importing the *os* module to get all the information.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.os.name
'posix'
>>> platform.uname()
('Darwin', 'mainframe.local', '15.3.0', 'Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64', 'x86_64', 'i386')
```

A nice and tidy layout for reporting purpose can be achieved using this line:

```
for i in zip(['system', 'node', 'release', 'version', 'machine', 'processor'], platform.uname()):print i[0], ':', i[1]
```

That gives this output:

```
system : Darwin
node : mainframe.local
release : 15.3.0
version : Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
machine : x86_64
processor : i386
```

Usually the operating system version is missing, but you should know if you are running Windows, Linux or Mac, a platform-independent way is to use this test:

```
In []: for i in [platform.linux_distribution(), platform.mac_ver(), platform.win32_ver()]:
   ....:     if i[0]:
   ....:         print 'Version: ', i[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

In the same vein....

```
import platform

is_windows = (platform.system().lower().find("win") > -1)

if(is_windows):
    lv_dll = LV_dll("my_so_dll.dll")
else:
    lv_dll = LV_dll("./my_so_dll.so")
```

Comment: This is problematic if you are on a Mac since platform.system() returns "Darwin" on a Mac and "Darwin".lower().find("win") = 3.

Comment: is_windows = platform.system().lower().startswith("win") or False

Answer (score 4):

Check the available tests with module *platform* and print the answer out for your system:

```
import platform

print dir(platform)

for x in dir(platform):
    if x[0].isalnum():
        try:
            result = getattr(platform, x)()
            print "platform." + x + ": " + result
        except TypeError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for both Python and [Jython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython).

module *os_identify.py*:

```
import platform
import os

# This module contains functions to determine the basic type of
# OS we are running on.
# Contrary to the functions in the `os` and `platform` modules,
# these allow to identify the actual basic OS,
# no matter whether running on the `python` or `jython` interpreter.

def is_linux():
    try:
        platform.linux_distribution()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def is_windows():
    try:
        platform.win32_ver()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def is_mac():
    try:
        platform.mac_ver()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def name():
    if is_linux():
        return "Linux"
    elif is_windows():
        return "Windows"
    elif is_mac():
        return "Mac"
    else:
        return "<unknown>"
```

Use like this:

```
import os_identify

print "My OS: " + os_identify.name()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Mac OS X and run `platform.system()` you get [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)), because Mac OS X  is built on Apple's Darwin OS. Darwin is the kernel of Mac OS X  and is essentially Mac OS X without the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple Enum implementation like the following. There isn't any need for external libraries!

```
import platform
from enum import Enum

class OS(Enum):
    def checkPlatform(osName):
        return osName.lower() == platform.system().lower()

    MAC = checkPlatform("darwin")
    LINUX = checkPlatform("linux")
    WINDOWS = checkPlatform("windows")  # I haven't tested this one
```

Simply you can access them with the Enum value:

```
if OS.LINUX.value:
    print("Cool. It is Linux")
```

PS: It is Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the code in **[`pyOSinfo`](https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date)** which is part of the **pip-date** package, to get the most relevant OS information, as seen from your Python distribution.

One of the most common reasons people want to check their OS is for terminal compatibility and if certain system commands are available. Unfortunately, the success of this checking is somewhat dependent on your Python installation and OS. For example, *`uname`* is not available on most Windows Python packages. The above Python program will show you the output of the most commonly used built-in functions, already provided by `os, sys, platform, site`.

[image]

So the best way to get only the essential code is looking at *that* as an example.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54582331/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This a function I use to make adjustments on my code so it runs on Windows, Linux and macOS:

```py
import sys

def get_os(osoptions={'linux':'linux', 'Windows':'win', 'macos':'darwin'}):
    '''
    Get OS to allow code specifics
    '''
    opsys = [k for k in osoptions.keys() if sys.platform.lower().find(osoptions[k].lower()) != -1]
    try:
        return opsys[0]
    except:
        return 'unknown_OS'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to find this. The easiest way is to use the *os* package:

```
import os

print(os.name)
```

Comment: This was already covered in the first answer 14 years ago. What is new?