# How can I find the current OS in Python?

Tags: python, cross-platform, platform-specific

As the title says, how can I find the current operating system in python?

Comment: Windows: `os.name == 'nt'`. Mac/Linux/BSD: `os.name == 'posix'`.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

I usually use [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) to get the platform. `sys.platform` will distinguish between linux, other unixes, and OS X, while `os.name` is "`posix`" for all of them.

For much more detailed information, use the [platform module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#module-platform). This has cross-platform functions that will give you information on the machine architecture, OS and OS version, version of Python, etc. Also it has os-specific functions to get things like the particular linux distribution.

Comment: I would not recommend either of these two. The more reliable way is `platform.system()`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071295/207661.

Answer (score 418):

If you want user readable data but still detailed, you can use [platform.platform()](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.platform)

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-3.3.0-8.fc16.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-16-Verne'
```

`platform` also has some other useful methods:

```
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> platform.release()
'XP'
>>> platform.version()
'5.1.2600'
```

Here's a few different possible calls you can make to identify where you are, linux_distribution and dist seem to have gone from recent python versions, so they have a wrapper function here.

```
import platform
import sys

def linux_distribution():
  try:
    return platform.linux_distribution()
  except:
    return "N/A"

def dist():
  try:
    return platform.dist()
  except:
    return "N/A"

print("""Python version: %s
dist: %s
linux_distribution: %s
system: %s
machine: %s
platform: %s
uname: %s
version: %s
mac_ver: %s
""" % (
sys.version.split('\n'),
str(dist()),
linux_distribution(),
platform.system(),
platform.machine(),
platform.platform(),
platform.uname(),
platform.version(),
platform.mac_ver(),
))
```

The outputs of this script ran on a few different systems (Linux, Windows, Solaris, MacOS) and architectures (x86, x64, Itanium, power pc, sparc) is available here: https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version

e.g. Solaris on sparc gave:

```
Python version: ['2.6.4 (r264:75706, Aug  4 2010, 16:53:32) [C]']
dist: ('', '', '')
linux_distribution: ('', '', '')
system: SunOS
machine: sun4u
platform: SunOS-5.9-sun4u-sparc-32bit-ELF
uname: ('SunOS', 'xxx', '5.9', 'Generic_122300-60', 'sun4u', 'sparc')
version: Generic_122300-60
mac_ver: ('', ('', '', ''), '')
```

or MacOS on M1

```
Python version: ['2.7.16 (default, Dec 21 2020, 23:00:36) ', '[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.30.4) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=sign+stri'] 
dist: ('', '', '') 
linux_distribution: ('', '', '') 
system: Darwin 
machine: arm64 
platform: Darwin-20.3.0-arm64-arm-64bit 
uname: ('Darwin', 'Nautilus.local', '20.3.0', 'Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:06:51 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101', 'arm64', 'arm') 
version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:06:51 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 
mac_ver: ('10.16', ('', '', ''), 'arm64')
```

Comment: `platform.linux_distribution()` is depreciated, to be removed in 3.8. Consider changing to the [`distro`](https://pypi.org/project/distro/) package. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution) for more details.

Comment: @TylerGubala Makes sence that it is deprecated, since it was not available on all platforms to begin with. It was always spotty but I included it here, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: This is much cleaner than the other options.

Comment: @JensTimmerman But I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 a few months ago (using the free upgrade provided by Microsoft for eligible devices). But when I run `print(platform.system(), platform.release())`, it prints `Windows 10`. Can you tell me what the reason is and how do I resolve it?

Comment: @NameError sounds like this could be a bug in Windows, in python, or expected behaviour, I don't have access to a win10 or 11 machine right now so I can not test this, you could try opening an issue  for python, the logich here doens't seem to include windows 11 yet: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/platform.py

Comment: FYI: AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'  MacOS 12.3.1 python_version 3.9.5

Comment: @JayRizzo yep, seems like it's also gone on python 3.10 on my linux machine, I've updated my answer and also added int inside a wrapper function.

Comment: Thanks @JensTimmerman!  Also if anyone wants to get the `name of the MacOS` they are using I built this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722226/1896134 & also posted it on my github.

Answer (score 55):

```py
import os
print(os.name)
```

This gives you the essential information you will usually need. To distinguish between, say, different editions of Windows, you will have to use a platform-specific method.

Comment: On the mac, os.name gives "posix", which for my case does not help - sys.platform did the trick

Comment: in windows it is showing nt only

Comment: On solaris, it's showing posix too. :p

Answer (score 21):

https://docs.python.org/library/os.html

To complement Greg's post, if you're on a posix system, which includes MacOS, Linux, Unix, etc. you can use os.uname() to get a better feel for what kind of system it is.

Comment: Although your answer was fist and was correct, Greg Hewgill's answer was more complete, I appreciate your answer and advise you to, post more then just links, in the future.

Comment: Yeah, it's the fastest gun in the west problem. I tend to post things quickly then edit with more info.

Comment: I usually wait to answer my questions an I come back to them to see if there are any better posts even after I have accepted one.

Answer (score 13):

Something along the lines:

```
import os
if os.name == "posix":
    print(os.system("uname -a"))
# insert other possible OSes here
# ...
else:
    print("unknown OS")
```

Comment: Your answer is the real answer