# I want to get python to output a png file

Tags: python, image, numpy, png, output

I am currently trying to get a picture that I have, or even one on the web that I can link to, to output from my python code from an if statement.

Here's the code:

```
if c >= 50:
    print '\nYou have been mauled by a bear\n'
    # I want to output a picture of a bear here
    quit()
```

I have a counter for c, and if it hits 50 I want it to print out that You have been mauled by a bear, and then on the screen have a bear pop up, whether the bear image is just a file in the same folder, or if it links to a webpage that I have the bear image hosted at.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you running this Python program? What's the environment? Command-line, web page, what?

Comment: It's just a raw .py file that i'm running in terminal, nothing special.
There's no main script or anything along those lines either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["open", "hi.jpg"])
```

This should also work on other systems if you substitute "open" with whatever program you use to open images.

Comment: What program is standard for opening images on an ubuntu linux system?

Comment: Looks like it's "eog."  I can't verify this for myself since I don't own an Ubuntu system.  http://chrisjean.com/2009/02/17/easily-view-images-from-terminal-in-ubuntu/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I got it to work as an if statement taking just a slice of the string.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, I would use image module from [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bear.png")
im.show()
```

Other ways would be to use one of the following: wxWindows, pyQt, pyGTK, or Tkinter

Comment: also, where would the image have to be stored? The same directory as the file?

Comment: @KevinShaffer you can store the image anywhere as long as you use the correct path, `im = Image.open(r"\some\dir\to\image\bear.png")`.