# Python: How to determine the specific Linux distribution being used?

Tags: python, linux

I would like to know how to determine the precise Linux distribution I am on (excluding version numbers), from within a Python script and define a variable as equal to it. Now, I should clarify and say that I have seen these two questions:

- [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)
- [How can I find the current OS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python)

and neither one was helpful to me as, the first of these questions had answers that were very generalized and merely returned `posix` for all Linux distributions. The second question's answers weren't helpful as I sometimes operate on some more obscure distributions like Manjaro Linux and Sabayon Linux. The most applicable answer to the second question, was `platform.linux_distribution()`, which on Manjaro, returns:

```
('', '', '')
```

which as you can see is not helpful. Now I know a way I can get half-way to an acceptable answer, as:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["lsb_release", "-si"])
```

returns the output (on Manjaro Linux, of course):

```
ManjaroLinux
0
```

but defining a variable:

```
a=call(["lsb_release", "-si"])
```

gives an a with the value:

```
>>> a
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [24]: open('/etc/lsb-release').readline().strip().split('=')[-1]
Out[24]: 'LinuxMint'
```

Comment: This is the one I will be accepting as it is the first one to give me the exact output I was looking for.

Comment: @BrentonHorne does this answer also print out the version of the OS in your case?

Comment: Nope, this question is just about the distro's name, not so much the version. I usually use rolling-release model distros (which Manjaro and Sabayon are) for which version numbers are irrelevant.

Comment: This piece of information should be explicitly added to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The 'a' is just the exit status, try:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = "lsb_release -si"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: For me `output` is returning `b'ManjaroLinux\n'`, any way to strip away the `b` and `\n`?

Comment: This returns just the OS and no version in my case.

Comment: @MikeVella Returns `"b'ManjaroLinux'"`.

Comment: just `output.strip()` then - the `b` prefix indicates that this is a bytes literal and the `b` is ignored - it will behave as a normal string, there's more detail on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) but you can almost certainly not worry about it.

Comment: as @Rolbrok has pointed out, output.decode().rstrip('\n') will work

Answer (score 2):

Replace call with check_output.

```
from subprocess import check_output
a = check_output(["lsb_release", "-si"])
```

Comment: Same as with Mike's answer, this provides no version for the OS (at least mine).

Answer (score 1):

What about `open("/etc/issue","r").read()`?

Comment: Returns for me `'Manjaro Linux \\r  (\\n) (\\l)\n\n\n'`, if you can strip away ` \\r  (\\n) (\\l)\n\n\n` from that I will accept this answer.

Comment: In my case this provides more info (and it's simpler) than using Mike's code. Mike's simply returns `elementary OS`, while this one returns `'elementary OS Freya \\n \\l\n'`. There are garbage chars but it gives the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try subprocess.check_output.
Based on docs: "Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string." Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Code:

```
a = subprocess.check_output(["lsb_release", "-si"])
```

In my case, output was:

```
'Ubuntu\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the link I linked to in the 2nd answer : https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version

you notice that platform.dist is a way better method of determining the current linux platform, however this is deprecated in python 3.5 and is gone in 3.8. It seems like there hardly is a good answer for this.

However weird OS'es will sometimes still not define this, but there is also absolutely no guarentee that lsb_release will be available on a system...

```
dist: ('redhat', '5.8', 'Final')
dist: ('debian', '4.0', '')
dist: ('centos', '6.3', 'Final')
dist: ('fedora', '16', 'Verne')
dist: ('SuSE', '11.3', 'x86_64')
dist: ('Ubuntu', '12.10', 'quantal')
```