# Case Sensitive Sort Windows Command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a Python file which calls a *case sensitive* sorting routine provided by the underlying OS. This program was originally tested in *Unix*.

The code fragment looks as follows:

```
def sort(path, filename, args=''):
   s = 'LC_ALL=C sort -S 50% --parallel=4 {0} {1} -o {1}'
   status = subprocess.call(s.format(args, os.path.join(path, filename)), shell=True)
   if status != 0:
      raise Exception('unable to sort file: {}'.format(filename))
```

However, running this program in *Windows* throws the error

```
"LC_ALL=C :Command not found"
```

and the default "sort" routine in Windows is case sensitive.

Is there any corresponding case sensitive sort routine that I can call in Windows or modify this command to remove this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In `Unix`, [`LC_ALL`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763) is the environment variable that overrides localisation settings. You can override localisation settings in the Windows `sort` command with the `/L` flag.

Try the following. *I didn't test it*. The Windows sort command is put together based on the [documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/sort.html). 
Also, for platform determination, take a look at [How can I find the current OS in Python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python).

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess


def sort(path, filename, args=''):
    if 'win' in sys.platform.lower():
        s = 'sort /L /C {0} /o {1}'
    else:
        s = 'LC_ALL=C sort -S 50% --parallel=4 {0} {1} -o {1}'
    status = subprocess.call(s.format(args, os.path.join(path, filename)), shell=True)
    if status != 0:
      raise Exception('unable to sort file: {}'.format(filename))
```

Comment: its still not case-sensitive. Even on the documentation link you provided, it says "The sort is always case insensitive". I need to do case sensitive sorting

Comment: You have to specify the "C" locale and input file, plus the `args` isn't portable, so you can probably just ignore it: `filepath = os.path.join(path, filename);` `s = 'sort.exe /C /L C "{0}" /o "{0}"'.format(filepath);` `subprocess.check_call(s)`.

Comment: The `/C` option for a case sensitive sort is only available in the Windows 7+ version of sort.exe. Note that Windows compares lower-case letters as less than upper-case letters, unless you're using the C locale, which simply compares the code points (i.e. ASCIIbetical order).