# Get or Retrieve OS versions and architectures from a library package and download it with launchpad API

Tags: python, ubuntu, launchpad

How to get OS versions, builds(architectures) versions of packages?

As I know, there are similar Python packages such as launchpadlib. However, I cannot get OS versions, package builds with this library.
I have searched but haven't found any package(s) that can give me all this information.

Implementation with html parser:

**get os series**

`[('warty', '4.10'), ('hoary', '5.04'), ('breezy', '5.10'), ('dapper', '6.06'), ('edgy', '6.10'), ('feisty', '7.04'), ('gutsy', '7.10'), ('hardy', '8.04'), ('intrepid', '8.10'), ('jaunty', '9.04'), ('karmic', '9.10'), ('lucid', '10.04'), ('maverick', '10.10'), ('natty', '11.04'), ('oneiric', '11.10'), ('precise', '12.04'), ('quantal', '12.10'), ('raring', '13.04'), ('saucy', '13.10'), ('trusty', '14.04'), ('utopic', '14.10'), ('vivid', '15.04'), ('wily', '15.10'), ('xenial', '16.04'), ('yakkety', '16.10'), ('zesty', '17.04'), ('artful', '17.10'), ('bionic', '18.04')]`

**get package builds**

```
libc6-dev
['amd64', 'i386', 'powerpc']
```

**get package versions**

```
libc6-dev
['2.3.2.ds1-13ubuntu2', '2.3.2.ds1-13ubuntu2.2', '2.3.2.ds1-13ubuntu2.2', '2.3.2.ds1-13ubuntu2.3']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the current OS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python)

Comment: no, I want to retrieve os series, ubuntu packages. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu:

get your os version with :

```
 >>> import platform
 >>> platform.platform()
```

get your build package and versions with :

```
 >>> import subprocess
 >>> output = subprocess.check_output("apt-cache policy libc6-dev",shell=True)

 >>> manipulate output as string.
```

the shell output for the `apt-cache policy` is:

`libc6-dev:   Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu10   Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu10

 Version table:  *** 2.23-0ubuntu10 500
         500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
         500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: thank u. but this is not thing I want.
My purpose is all of packages of various architecture, verions.

Comment: thank u. but this is not thing I want.
My purpose is all of packages of various architecture, versions.
For Example.

os versions retrieve
input : Ubuntu
output : [('warty', '4.10'),~~~('bionic', '18.04')]

package architectures

input : ubuntu, warty, libc6
output : ['amd64', 'i386'~~]

package versions
input : ubuntu, warty, libc6, amd64
output : ['2.?.?.ds1-13ubuntu2', ~~~]

sorry to lack of my explain.