# Windows server and windows desktop deference with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-server

I want to make a script in python which can differentiate between windows server and windows desktop. OS and platform are giving same result for both, is there any way to differ them on the basis of python script?
The main problem I'm facing is script is giving same output for server and desktop no difference it's showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the current OS in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `platform.release()`

**Ex:**

```
import platform
print(platform.release())
```

if OS is Desktop:

```
7
```

If OS is Server:

```
2008ServerR2
```

Comment: I already tried this in windows server and it's giving output only   "10"  in windows server 2016. The main problem I'm facing is script is giving same output for server and desktop no difference it's showing.