# Why does the python installed by conda's defaults report the wrong mac platform?

Tags: python, macos, conda

I use `miniconda` on `macOS` Ventura (13.3). When doing an experiment recently, I found that `platform.platform()` called from `python` installed from the `defaults` channel reports a different (and incorrect) version of macOS compared to both the system python and python when installed from `conda-forge`.

| Source | `platform.platform()` value |
| --- | --- |
| Python 3.11 installed from `defaults` | `'macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit'` |
| Python 3.11 installed from `conda-forge` | `'macOS-13.3.1-x86_64-i386-64bit'` |
| Native Python 3.11 installed by `xcode-select` | `'macOS-13.3.1-x86_64-i386-64bit'` |

What's causing this discrepancy? Is it due to the build chain for `defaults`?

##### Update

On further investigation, (thanks, 
[user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105751/why-does-the-python-installed-by-condas-defaults-report-the-wrong-mac-platform?noredirect=1#comment134219019_76105751)) environments created by defaults appears to be overriding the system's `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` to tell python to find a different one:

```bash
[I] > cat /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist | grep string
    <string>6B08394E-D0A4-11ED-8DAB-1CA630367858</string>
    <string>22E261</string>
    <string>1983-2023 Apple Inc.</string>
    <string>macOS</string>
    <string>13.3.1</string>
    <string>13.3.1</string>
    <string>16.4</string>
[I] > python                                    (base)
Python 3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 04:29:44)
[Clang 14.0.6 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import plistlib
>>> fn  = "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
>>> with open(fn, "rb") as f:
...     pl = plistlib.load(f)
...
>>> pl
{'BuildID': '6B08394E-D0A4-11ED-8DAB-1CA630367858', 'ProductBuildVersion': '22E261',
'ProductCopyright': '1983-2023 Apple Inc.',
'ProductName': 'Mac OS X',
'ProductUserVisibleVersion': '10.16',
'ProductVersion': '10.16',
'iOSSupportVersion': '16.4'}
>>> quit()
```

#### Update 2

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65402241/4431535) to a question found by [merv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105751/why-does-the-python-installed-by-condas-defaults-report-the-wrong-mac-platform?noredirect=1#comment134221669_76105751) (Thanks!) suggests that the issue is that the default python is indeed compiled for an older version of macOS. macOS itself overrides the contents of `SystemVersion.plist` for software compiled on older OSs. Assuming that defaults is compiled on older software to provide broader support for more OS versions, this tracks.

Comment: That's weird... it's supposed to [read that version info](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/platform.py#L414) from `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`, which should give the same results no matter how Python itself was configured.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65290242/pythons-platform-mac-ver-reports-incorrect-macos-version

Comment: Conda Forge maintains deeper backward support than Anaconda (10.9 versus 10.13), so I don't think version targeting explains it. Rather, there must be something explicit they do that triggers the setting of the `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1`state. It might also be worth noting that it's not Python or Anaconda specific. For example, using the `cat` provided by `conda-forge::coreutils` in an environment, will similarly show the `SystemVersionCompat.plist`.