# Detection Docker environment Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am running a docker image of Python code in two different environments.

1. In Windows via cmd `docker run --rm --name test -p 9000:8080  estimate_variance`
2. In Linux via terminal `docker run --rm --name test -p 9000:8080  estimate_variance`

The code itself uses `aws S3 bucket` and for some reason when I am using (1) and authenticate `aws sso login`  it gives me an error of credentials so I had to supply `aws_access_key_id aws_secret_access_key aws_session_token` when I've created the client `s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id =....,aws_secret_access_key = ..., aws_session_token=..`

while in (2) the authentication works fine.

Is there any way to detect within the code which environment I am running?

Something like

```
import boto3
env = detect_env()
if env =='linux':
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
elif env =='win':
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id =....,aws_secret_access_key = ..., 
    aws_session_token=..)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10091465

Comment: @LorenzoMogicato No, the docker itself runs on Linux in any case so using `platform` will return `linux` in both cases

Comment: Oh sorry, I got the point of your question now. I will try something and will let you know in case :p

Comment: Show us the full docker run commands

Comment: @Paolo they are identical, I have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround  I found was to set environment variable `FROM_WINDOWS` only in (1) like:

`docker run --env FROM_WINDOWS=1 --rm --name test -p 9000:8080  estimate_variance`

and then check it in the code

```
import os
def detect_env:
    if os.getenv('FROM_WINDOWS') is not None:
       return 'win'
    else:
       return 'linux'
```