# Possible values from sys.platform?

Tags: python, cross-platform

What are the possible return values from the following command?

```
import sys
print sys.platform
```

I know there is a lot of possibilities, so I'm mainly interested in the "main" ones (Windows, Linux, Mac OS)

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform

Comment: For Python 3.9 see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#sys.platform

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Mac OS X (10.4, 10.5, 10.7, 10.8):

```
darwin
```

Linux (2.6 kernel):

```
linux2
```

Windows XP 32 bit:

```
win32
```

Versions in brackets have been checked - other/newer versions are likely to be the same.

Comment: What about OS X versions higher than 10.5, are they also labeled under 'darwin'? What about Linux kernel versions higher than 2.6? Windows versions higher than XP?

Comment: @Dennis Clarified in answer - the listed versions are the ones I have checked. I'm almost certain all OS X versions will be `darwin`, all 2.x linux kernels will be `linux2`, and Windows will be win32 or win64.. but, I've not checked

Comment: Newer versions of Linux may have "linux3" instead of "linux2".

Comment: @MarioVilas: No, Python stuck to linux2 even for linux3 kernels because there is no difference from Python's perspective.

Comment: A 64 bit Python installation on 64 bit Windows will also output "win32". Using `platform.system()` may be a less confusing solution ("Windows" vs "Linux").

Comment: The list is larger and isn't clearly [documented] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), for example in OpenBSD is "openbsd6"

Answer (score 198):

```
┍━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┑
│ System              │ Value               │
┝━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┥
│ Linux               │ linux or linux2 (*) │
│ Windows             │ win32               │
│ Windows/Cygwin      │ cygwin              │
│ Windows/MSYS2       │ msys                │
│ Mac OS X            │ darwin              │
│ OS/2                │ os2                 │
│ OS/2 EMX            │ os2emx              │
│ RiscOS              │ riscos              │
│ AtheOS              │ atheos              │
│ FreeBSD 7           │ freebsd7            │
│ FreeBSD 8           │ freebsd8            │
│ FreeBSD N           │ freebsdN            │
│ OpenBSD 6           │ openbsd6            │
│ AIX                 │ aix (**)            │
┕━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┙
```

(*) Prior to Python 3.3, the value for any Linux version is always `linux2`; after, it is `linux`.

(**) Prior Python 3.8 could also be `aix5` or `aix7`; use `sys.platform.startswith()`

Comment: You should make a list of this.

Comment: Probably the most useful answer as of this writing. Additional karma for the stylish ASCII-art spreadsheet.

Comment: What about current `macOS` systems? Do they still resolve to `darwin`?

Comment: I'm getting "linux"

Comment: @blubberdiblub yes.

Comment: The list is larger and isn't clearly [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), for example in OpenBSD it reports "openbsd6"

Comment: What about `android`?

Comment: What is it for ubuntu ?

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux distro, but I tested this out anyway and it's `linux`.

Comment: @G.Vanem, `android` is considered as `linux` (or `linux2`).

Comment: now with 3.11 there are also emscripten and wasi platform https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.platlibdir

Comment: Recent versions of MSYS2 now return `cygwin`. BEWARE!

Answer (score 22):

> As others have indicated, sys.platform
>   is derived from the name that the
>   system vendor gives their system.
>   However, Python also adds
>   plat- to sys.path, so
>   you can look at all the plat-*
>   directories in the Python
>   distribution.
>
> This gives you the list
>
> aix3 aix4 atheos beos5 darwin freebsd2
>   freebsd3 freebsd4 freebsd5 freebsd6
>   freebsd7 generic irix5 irix6 linux2
>   mac netbsd1 next3 os2emx riscos sunos5
>   unixware7
>
> Of course, sys.platform can have
>   additional values, when Python gets
>   compiled on a system for which no
>   platform-specific directory has been
>   created.

From [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-August/405454.html).

Comment: By digging through the sourcecode there are a few more common: `win32`, `os2`, `unknown`

Comment: On Python 3.3 and later `linux2` becomes `linux`. [source](http://bugs.python.org/issue12326)

Comment: @Deqing: fixed three years later :)

Answer (score 9):

FreeBSD 7.0: `freebsd7`.  FreeBSD8 but build performed on previous version, same answer.

So be aware you get the platform used for the build, not necessarely the one you're running on.

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 29 2013, OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks is still labeled Darwin.

Comment: Darwin is the OS X kernel. To get the OS X version number, use [platform.mac_ver()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.mac_ver)