# Python os.name return nt on windows 7

Tags: python

Python os.name returns "nt" on windows 7

I'm using os.name to get the name of current operating system under which current script is running. But strangely, instead of "windows 7" it returns "nt".

Here is the code:

```
import os

print(os.name)
```

And result:

```
nt
```

Comment: nothing strange about it…According to the documentation: os.name - "The name of the operating system dependent module imported. The following names have currently been registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'os2', 'ce', 'java', 'riscos'."

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553129/when-to-use-os-name-sys-platform-or-platform-system

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had read that but haven't paid attention to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `platform` module to check:

```
In [244]: import platform

In [247]: platform.version()
Out[247]: '6.1.7601'

In [248]: platform.system()
Out[248]: 'Windows'

In [249]: platform.release()
Out[249]: '7'

In [250]: platform.win32_ver()
Out[250]: ('7', '6.1.7601', 'SP1', 'Multiprocessor Free')

In [268]: platform.platform()
Out[268]: 'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
```

So just use `platform.system() == 'Windows' and platform.release() == 7` to check ;)

Or simplier `'Windows-7' in platform.platform()`.

Comment: I think you'd better check both `platform.system()` and `platform.release()` though...

Answer (score 5):

The os-module lets us run different code dependent on which operating system the code is running on.

***nt*** means that you are running windows, and
***posix*** mac

If you want to check if OS is Windows or Linux or OSX then the most reliable way is [platform.system().](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system)
If you want to make OS-specific calls but via built-in Python modules posix or nt then use os.name.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()

'Windows' # for Linux it prints 'Linux', Mac it prints `'Darwin'
```

Refer here for more. [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 2):

'nt' means 'New Technology' which is come with the release of a 32-bit version initially. But after that, the name carried over simply without any specific meaning.
for further information please refer: [what is NT?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), `os.name` currently  has one of the following: 'posix', 'nt', 'os2', 'ce', 'java', 'riscos'. What you are after might be [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform).