# How do I check what platform (OS) I'm running in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

Is there any way to check what platform I'm running with Python 2.7?
For example using the platform module:

```
import platform
print platform.system()
print platform.release()
```

I get:

```
Linux
2.6.32-312-ec2
```

But if I read from the file `/etc/issue` by running a Linux command line command within Python I can get exactly what platform I'm running:

```
import command
print commands.getoutput('cat /etc/issue')
```

.

```
 Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l
```

Is there any other way in Python to know that I'm running Debian GNU Linux 6.0?

Comment: What does ```sys.platorm``` get you?

Comment: `python -mplatform` or `platform.platform()` in the code

Comment: related: [When to use os.name, sys.platform, or platform.system?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4553129/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `sys.platform` to get the platform. `sys.platform` will distinguish between linux, other unixes, and OS X while `os.name` is more general.

These are done by:

```
import sys
print(sys.platform)

import os
print(os.name)
```

For much more detailed information, use the `platform` module. This has cross-platform functions that will give you information on the machine architecture, OS and OS version, version of Python, etc. Also it has os-specific functions to get things like the particular linux distribution.

A small example, which actually seems the best way to do what you want:

```
import platform
print(platform.platform())
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably `platform.uname()` or `platform.platform()`

at a guess at least (or potentially `sys.platform` may provide sufficient data)

For example:

```
import platform
print(platform.platform())

import sys
print(sys.platform)

import os
print(os.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

try in your python2 interpreter

```
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.platform())
Linux-5.4.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-20.04-focal
>>> 
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.platform)
linux2
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> print(os.name)
posix
>>>
```