# How to check whether the system is FreeBSD in a python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, freebsd

I would like to add a check in a `python` 2.7.x script in the form of

```
if __check_freebsd__():
    # run actions which would only work on FreeBSD (e.g. create a jail)
elif __check_debian__():
    # run an alternative that runs on Debian-based systems
else:
    raise Error("unsupported OS")
```

How would the `__check_freebsd__` function look like?

I have the following code for `__check_debian__` already:

```
try:
    lsb_release_id_short = sp.check_output([lsb_release, "-d", "-s"]).strip().decode("utf-8")
    ret_value = "Debian" in lsb_release_id_short
    return ret_value
except Exception:
    return False
```

So you don't have to bother with it (suggestions for improvements are welcome, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [in documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.system),

```
platform.system()
```

returns the platform OS name, so you can use this. In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553129/when-to-use-os-name-sys-platform-or-platform-system) you can see also different approaches to check the underlying OS.

Comment: `if platform.system() == 'FreeBSD'` should work, as far as I am concerned. Karl asked about freeBSD check, so I think I don't need to check Linux distros. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Works on FreeBSD 9.3 and FreeBSD 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [**`os.uname`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.uname).

I'm not 100% certain, but it would probably be something like `os.uname()[0] == "FreeBSD"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> from sys import platform
>>> platform()
# on my system I get
'linux' # check string for freebsd
```

Also:

```
# below are my results
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux' # would be 'FreeBSD' if I was using that
>>> platform.platform()
'Linux-3.19.0-15-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-15.04-vivid'
```

Comment: `platform.linux_platform()` returns `('', '', '')` in FreeBSD 9.3 (running on `qemu` 2.2).

Comment: @KarlRichter it's only for linux, so it wouldn't work for FreeBSD I suppose. platform.system() is cross platform though as is sys.platform

Comment: I see. Then it's not an answer to my question, is it? Maybe this is due to `qemu`?

Comment: @KarlRichter No, it is. sys.platform, platform.system and platform.platform all give you the info you want. The first two in a more straight-forward fashion. I had included the platform.linux_platform also, I can't remember why. But I edited it out earlier.