# What is sys.platform used for in python?

Tags: python

I wanted to know what the sys.platform does in python and what it is useful for. What type of projects would i want to use it for?

Comment: lso please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553129/when-to-use-os-name-sys-platform-or-platform-system

Answer (score 1):

`sys.platform` lets you inspect what operating system/platform the code is running on. This can be very useful, for example, in projects which interface with non-Python aspects of the operating system. There are details about the possible values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform).

Edit: [this search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sys.platform+in%3Afile+language%3APython&type=Code&ref=searchresults) shows how people are using `sys.platform` on github.