# find() character in string error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

mypath = "D:\inetpub\wwwroot"

if mypath:
        try:
                print "Path: %s" % mypath
                if mypath.find("/"):
                        print "OS: Linux/Unix"
                elif mypath.find(":"):
                        print "OS: Windows"
                else:
                        print "OS: Unknown"
        except:
                print "Error"
else:
        print "[?] OS detection failure."
```

execution output:

```
$ python test.py
Path: D:\inetpub\wwwroot
OS: Linux/Unix
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting the opposite result as I expect. Or is there a better way to do this? "/" -> Linux/Unix and ":" -> Windows

Comment: If you want to detect the OS, why don't you read `sys.platform` directly? If it contains `linux`, then it's Linux. If it contains `win32`, then it's Windows. If it contains `darwin`, then it's Mac OS X. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform for more.

Comment: this was just an example, I'm not relying on this to detect OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

mypath = "D:\\inetpub\\wwwroot"

if mypath:
        try:
                print "Path: %s" % mypath
                if mypath.find("/") >= 0:
                        print "OS: Linux/Unix"
                elif mypath.find(":"):
                        print "OS: Windows"
                else:
                        print "OS: Unknown"
        except:
                print "Error"
else:
        print "[?] OS detection failure."
```

You need to escape `\` otherwise it will assume that the next character has a speacial meaning/binary representation (such as `\n´,`\t`).

or try:

```
mypath = r'D:\inetpub\wwwroot'
```

a better way is to do:

```
from os.path import abspath
print abspath('D:/inetpub/')
```

It will automaticly re-work your path to the system specific design, for instance / for linux and \ for Windows :)

or you can do:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    print 'Windows'
else:
    print 'Linux/Unix'
```

Comment: Python automatically does this (escapes the `'\'`) if the escape sequence is invalid.

Comment: Yepp but assuming this is stupid/lazy because you will end up with a `\a` or something similar one day and you'll wonder why :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `str.find`. [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns the index of a substring in a string, or `-1` otherwise. Because `-1` is `True` in a boolean context, you enter the `if` block. What you really want is the `in` operator:

```
>>> 'hello world'.find('foo')
-1
>>> bool(-1)
True
>>> 'foo' in 'hello world'
False
```

---

Your code now should therefore look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

mypath = r'D:\inetpub\wwwroot'  # use a raw string
if mypath:
    try:
        print 'Path:', mypath  # no need for formatting
        if '/' in mypath:
            print 'OS: Linux/Unix'
        elif ':' in mypath:
            print 'OS: Windows'
        else:
            print 'OS: Unknown'
    except:
        print 'Error'
else:
    print '[?] OS detection failure.'
```

---

Some suggestions:

- Use the new [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method when formatting. It is much more powerful, and is recommended over the old style formatting.
- You shouldn't have a bare `except` - it's always a good idea to except specific exceptions, and allows for easy debugging if an unexpected error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in

```
if "/" in mypath:
    print 'yay :)'
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

> The find() method should be used only if you need to know the position
>   of sub. To check if sub is a substring or not, use the in operator: