# Python: sys.platform Incorrect result

Tags: python, ubuntu, version

I use Python shell under Ubuntu 13.10. My Linux Kernel version is "3.11.0-13-generic". So why in Python variable "sys.platform" stored value "Linux2" instead of "Linux3"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform):

> *Changed in version 2.7.3:* Since lots of code check for `sys.platform == 'linux2'`, and there is no essential change between Linux 2.x and 3.x, `sys.platform` is always set to `'linux2'`, even on Linux 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform):

> sys.platform is always set to 'linux2', even on Linux 3.x. In Python
>   3.3 and later, the value will always be set to 'linux', so it is recommended to always use the startswith idiom presented above.

Answer (score 1):

Because `sys.platform` isn't a kernel version. It's a string added to the python binary or library when it's compiled. It's always linux2 on linux except after Python 3.3 when it changed to just `linux`.

[Possible values from sys.platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform)