# What are the potential results for platform.system()

Tags: python

What are the possible return values from the following command?

```
import platform
print platform.system()
```

I've seen the SO [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform), which is not the same question.
And I've looked at the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.system) but they only list:
'Linux', 'Windows', or 'Java'.
What else is there?
Do macs return "Mac"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`platform.system()` retrieves its information from [the `uname` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html) if available, or synthesizes a result if `uname` is not available. That means that there is no fixed set of possible returns—it gets it directly from the operating system, and the operating system can return whatever it wants there. For what it’s worth, Mac OS X will return `Darwin`. (If you’re interested, check [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/356997cccc21a3391175d20e9ef03d434675b496/Lib/platform.py#L906-L913).)

Comment: I typed exactly this in, just too late :)

Comment: this question is the first Google result for `what does "platform.system" print on freebsd` :(