# What would be the string returned from platform.system() for a Big-IP OS?

Tags: python, big-ip

brand new to python here so bear with me please. I am creating a script that has to perform backups for various devices. I have the following code:

```
def getOS():
if platform.system().upper() == 'JUNOS' :
    os = "junos"
elif platform.system().upper() == "WIN32"
    os = "windows"
elif platform.system().upper() == "DARWIN"
    os = "mac"
return os
```

How can I test for Big-IP? Additionally is there a list somewhere of the potential results for platform.system()?

I'm aware of the similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107019/what-are-the-potential-results-for-platform-system), however I'm looking for specifically Big-IP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the potential results for platform.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107019/what-are-the-potential-results-for-platform-system)

Answer (score 0):

`platform.system()` returns the `uname` system call. There is no DEFINITE return, it 100% relies on the OS.

Here is some more info on [uname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html)

Your best course of action would probably be running `platform.system()` on a Big-IP OS.

Comment: I do not currently have access to one, I am hoping someone else has done this previously and knows the result @ltd9938

Answer (score 0):

To see the TMOS version, you would run **tmsh show sys software**.

```
root@(ltm3)(cfg-sync Standalone)(Active)(/Common)(tmos)# show sys software

--------------------------------------------------
Sys::Software Status
Volume  Product   Version  Build  Active    Status
--------------------------------------------------
HD1.1    BIG-IP  13.1.0.5  0.0.5     yes  complete
HD1.2    BIG-IP  12.1.3.3  0.0.1      no  complete
HD1.3      none      none   none      no  complete
```