# Skip test depending on platform

Tags: nose

Is there a way to skip unit tests depending on the [platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform)? I have linux specific nosetests that use linux only libraries, that I would like to skip on our mac build.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you do it like so

Step one, create a decorator

```
def skip_if(condition):
    """Conditionally skips a test"""
    def wrapper(f):
        f.__test__ = not condition
        return f

    return wrapper
```

Step two, use `sys.platform` in your condition

```
import sys
@skip_if(sys.platform == "linux")
def test_linux_only()
    linus_torvalds()
```