# What is platform.system() output for MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, operating-system, python-3.7

I'm making a python application that is (hopefully) *OS agnostic*. This is being written in *python3.7* and the GUI is being constructed from Tkinter8.6. I am attempting to use *platform.system()* for determining the OS family.

I am setting the tkinter border fullscreen with one of two commands depending on the OS.The problem is I dont understand what platform should print for MacOS.

The code I am using will roughly look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import platform

root = Tk()
system = platform.system()

if system == 'Windows':
    root.state('zoomed')
elif system == 'Linux' or system == 'Darwin':
    root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
elif system == '':
    expectation = "Expected: 'Linux' 'Windows' or 'Darwin', Received: "
    raise OSError(expectation + system)
```

Peoples examples and the docs are conflicting and I dont have a Mac to test it on.

- The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system) say: "Returns the system/OS name, e.g. 'Linux', 'Windows', or 'Java'..."
- What several peoples posts keep repeating: "will return [darwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446209/possible-values-from-sys-platform) for MacOS"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `platform` library (`platform.system() == 'Darwin'`). The post you linked to uses the `sys` library (`sys.platform == 'darwin'`). With the library you are using, the string is 'Darwin'. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you also know why the docs list "Java" and not "Darwin?"

Comment: I honestly have no clue. Probably just didn't feel the need to enumerate all the options.