# How do I get the operating system name in a friendly manner using Python 2.5?

Tags: python

I tried:

```
print os.name
```

And the output I got was:

```
:nt
```

However, I want output more like "Windows 98", or "Linux".

After suggestions in this question, I also tried:

```
import os
print os.name
import platform
print platform.system()
print platform.release()
```

And my output was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/BIU1LR/Desktop/python_programs/program/platform.py", line 3, in <module>
    import platform
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/BIU1LR/Desktop/python_programs/program\platform.py", line 4, in <module>
    print platform.system()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'system'
```

I am using Python 2.5.2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OS name of server? Or OS name of client? (In case you're doing web development...)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-how-do-i-tell-what-os-im-running-on

Comment: import sys print(sys.version) give us the result so that we know what we're dealing with

Answer (score 36):

Try:

```
import platform
print platform.system(), platform.release()
```

I tried this on my computer with Python 2.6 and I got this as the output:

```
Windows XP
```

After your latest edits, I see that you called your script platform.py. This is causing a naming problem, as when you call `platform.system()` and `platform.release()`, it's looking in your file, and not Python's platform module. If you change the name of your file, all of your problems should be resolved.

Answer (score 13):

it is because you named your program "platform". Hence when importing the module "platform", your program is imported instead in a circular import.

Try renaming the file to test_platform.py, and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

```
import platform

platform.dist()
```

Answer (score 1):

well it depends on the OS:
   for example I had tested

```
    platform.system() - in linux works, AIX works
    platform.release()- in linux works, AIX gives a weird '1' with non other info 
    platform.dist()   - in linux works, AIX gives a nothing '','','' 
    os.name           - resolves 'posix' in both :S
```

Windows I really don't test nor care :P