# How can you find out what operating system the user is running?

Tags: python, operating-system, python-3.x

I want to find out what OS a person has in Python. I know I could always do this:

```
try:
    os.system(unixonlycommand)
except:
    os.system(windowsonlycommand)
```

But is there another way to do it?  A special module for that or something?

Comment: Reviewing this post might be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421357/how-do-i-get-the-operating-system-name-in-a-friendly-manner-using-python-2-5

Answer (score 5):

Use [`platform.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.system):

> Returns the system/OS name, e.g. `'Linux'`, `'Windows'`, or `'Java'`. An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.

You should also look at the other methods in the `platform` module, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Also relevant: [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform).