# Can python detect which OS is it running under?

Tags: python, windows, linux

Can python detect OS and then contruct a if/else statement for File System.

I would need to replace  C:\CobaltRCX\ in Fn string with the FileSys string.

```
import os.path, csv
from time import strftime

if os.path.?????:## Windows
   FileSys = r"C:\\working\\" 
else:   ##linux   
   FileSys = r"\\working\\" 

y=(strftime("%y%m%d"))
Fn = (r"C:\\working\\Setup%s.csv" %y)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on

Comment: platform.system() == platform.uname()[0] == 'Windows'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I usually just use this:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    pass # Windows
else:
    pass # other (unix)
```

#### edit:

Hopefully in response to your comments:

```
from time import strftime
import os

if os.name == 'nt': # Windows
    basePath = 'C:\\working\\'
else:
    basePath = '/working/'

Fn = '%sSetup%s.csv' % ( basePath, strftime( '%y%m%d' ) )
```

Comment: Huh? What do you mean with that?

Comment: The Fn string "C:\\working\\Setup%s.csv." How would 2nd variable. 1, the filesys the 2nd y the date. right now I have the date setup, need help with the string for "filesys" yada yada yada "date." thanks

Comment: Not sure if I answer it with my edit now, but I really don't get it. Please try to explain it using comprehensive english otherwise...

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry. You can also use os.path to concatenate multiple path sequences, if your path becomes more complex than this.

Answer (score 6):

see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689984/3752715

```
import platform 
plt = platform.system()

if   plt == "Windows":   print("Your system is Windows")
elif plt == "Linux":     print("Your system is Linux")
elif plt == "Darwin":    print("Your system is MacOS")
else:                    print("Unidentified system")
```

you can see my github repo https://github.com/sk3pp3r/PyOS and use pyos.py script

Answer (score 5):

Use `sys.platform`. You can find more information here http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.uname()
('Linux', 'ubuntu', '2.6.32-27-generic', '#49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 00:51:09 UTC 2010', 'x86_64')
>>> system = os.uname()
>>> print system[0] + '/' + system[1]
Linux/ubuntu
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
    import platform
    platform.uname()
```

It works both on linux as well as windows. FYI: os.uname() will not work on windows, though it works on linux. Platform is generic.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but if you're trying to determine the path separator, you can use

```
os.path.sep
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at os.uname

```
In [12]: os.uname()
Out[12]: 
('Darwin',
 'demitasse.local',
 '10.6.0',
 'Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386',
 'i386')
```

Answer (score 0):

For most usecases you should use the [`os.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) module. However if you need a more lean interface, try [`platinfo`](https://code.google.com/p/platinfo/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I just created the other day:

**CODE:**

```
def GetUserPlatform():
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        UsrWinVer = str(sys.getwindowsversion().major)
        print("Operating System: Windows " + UsrWinVer)
    else:
        print("Something else")

GetUserPlatform()
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: `platform.system()` is more consistent/reliable than `sys.platform`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/557406

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform
print(platform.uname().system)
```

This will give you Windows, Linux, etc.