# Is this possible to get the system level key events and re-produce system level key events in Python?

Tags: python, events, operating-system

I would like to have some under the hood level application that required to get the system level key press events and re-produce system level key press events using Python 3. Is there anyway to do so? Thanks.

Comment: This will be OS-dependent, so you should mention what you're using

Comment: Is there any cross-OS solutions for that?

Comment: I don't think so, the interfaces to do this both on windows and linux are somewhat arcane. I guess you could combine all the modules in the current answers with [operating system detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719063/can-python-detect-which-os-is-it-running-under) to give you something cross-platform. Let us know if you do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for getting input events, something like this would work in Linux. You have to find out which input device corresponds to the device you want to watch (e.g. keyboard) and pass it to the `InputDevice()` constructor. In my case it was `/dev/input/event3`.

```
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes
from select import select


while True:
    dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event3')  # look into /dev/input
    select([dev], [], [])
    for event in dev.read():
        print("type: ", event.type)
        print("code: ", event.code)
        if event.code == ecodes.KEY_ENTER:
            print("Hey, it was ENTER!")
```