# PyQt API for detecting OS

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm porting some code from C++/Qt to Python/PyQt.

What do I do  with

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    ...
#else
```

Is there a PyQt equivalent of the Qt macro Q_OS_WIN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you ever want to do this instead of using Python [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) from sys module?

```
import sys
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    print("win")
else:
    print("winner!")
```

I have to mention that `win32` is the same even if you run on x64 python.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a PyQt API for detecting the OS. Apparently there is not.

Comment: And if you think about this, it makes sense to not have one, when the language itself gives you the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C++, there is no preprocessor in Python. This means that you can't completely exclude blocks of code from being seen by the compiler/interpreter.

For most practical purposes, however, it is sufficient to place the relevant block of code inside a Python `if` statement.

Take a look at [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 0):

To test if the underlying operating system is a macintosh

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
MAC = hasattr(PyQt4.QtGui, "qt_mac_set_native_menubar")
```

To test if the underlying operating system is Linux/X11, BSD, Solaris

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
X11 = hasattr(PyQt4.QtGui, "qt_x11_wait_for_window_manager")
```

From Mark Summerfield's book

I don't know of a specific Windows test but if the two above returned None then it's likely the system is windows.