# How do I check the operating system in Python?

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I want to check the operating system (on the computer where the script runs).

I know I can use `os.system('uname -o')` in Linux, but it gives me a message in the console, and I want to write to a variable.

It will be okay if the script can tell if it is Mac, Windows or Linux. How can I check it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell What OS I am running on from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/how-can-i-tell-what-os-i-am-running-on-from-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 533, accepted):

You can use [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform):

```
from sys import platform
if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
    # linux
elif platform == "darwin":
    # OS X
elif platform == "win32":
    # Windows...
```

`sys.platform` has finer granularity than `sys.name`.

For the valid values, consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform).

See also the answer to [“What OS am I running on?”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/1513933)

Comment: Note that in cygwin, it returns `"cygwin"` not `"win32"` as someone might expect.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between linux and linux2 ?

Comment: what would the output for BSD be ?

Comment: Note that since Python 3.3, `"linux2"` is no longer a possible value of `platform` (see the linked docs for corroboration) and so if you only need to support Python 3.3 and later you can safely delete the ` or platform == "linux2"` clause from the first condition.

Comment: why is it win32 not win64?

Comment: @ohailolcat , for backward compatibility.  It will probably never change.  See the original patch that defined it this way for more info:  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/patches/2000-May/000648.html

Comment: if sys.platform.startswith('freebsd')

Comment: note, sys.name you mentioned doesn't exist in python 3.10.9

Answer (score 56):

If you want to know on which platform you are on out of "Linux", "Windows", or "Darwin" (Mac), without more precision, you should use:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'  # or 'Windows'/'Darwin'
```

The [`platform.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system) function uses `uname` internally.

Comment: I like this solution but I want to point out that from the docs it states that it will return `Linux`, `Windows`, `Java` or an empty string.https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/platform#platform.system

Comment: @BrandonBenefield, the enumeration is an example of possible values. On Apple devices, it returns “Darwin”.

Comment: "The platform.system function uses uname internally." that's for Linux, what about Windows?

Answer (score 16):

You can get a pretty coarse idea of the OS you're using by checking [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform).

Once you have that information you can use it to determine if calling something like [`os.uname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.uname) is appropriate to gather more specific information.  You could also use something like [Python System Information](https://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home) on unix-like OSes, or [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) for Windows.

There's also [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) if you want to do more in-depth inspection without wanting to care about the OS.

Comment: os.uname() returns an error on windows: >>> os.uname()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?

Answer (score 7):

More detailed information are available in the [`platform` module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html).

Comment: Does the `platform` module have any advantage over `sys.platform`? When would I want to use which approach?

Comment: @matth: You get more detailed, structured information from the `platform` module.  Just click the link for documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sys.platform`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this for all Kivy developers [`kivy.utils`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.2.0/api-kivy.utils.html):

```
from kivy.utils import platform
if platform == 'linux':
    do_linux_things()
```