# Django: How to manage development and production settings?

Tags: python, django

I have been developing a basic app. Now at the deployment stage it has become clear I have need for both a local settings and production settings.

It would be great to know the following:

- How best to deal with development and production settings.
- How to keep apps such as django-debug-toolbar only in a development environment.
- Any other tips and best practices for development and deployment settings.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88259/how-do-you-configure-django-for-simple-development-and-deployment/88331 and here https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) controls which settings file Django will load.

You therefore create separate configuration files for your respective environments (note that they can of course both `import *` from a separate, "shared settings" file), and use `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to control which one to use.

Here's how:

As noted in the Django documentation:

> The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax, e.g. mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.

So, let's assume you created `myapp/production_settings.py` and `myapp/test_settings.py` in your source repository.

In that case, you'd respectively set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.production_settings` to use the former and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.test_settings` to use the latter.

---

From here on out, the problem boils down to setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

### Setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` using a script or a shell

You can then use a bootstrap script or a process manager to load the correct settings (by setting the environment), or just run it from your shell before starting Django: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.production_settings`.

Note that you can run this export at any time from a shell — it does not need to live in your `.bashrc` or anything.

### Setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` using a Process Manager

If you're not fond of writing a bootstrap script that sets the environment (and there are very good reasons to feel that way!), I would recommend using a process manager:

- [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) lets you pass environment variables to managed processes using a [program's `environment` configuration key](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings).
- [Honcho](https://honcho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (a pure-Python equivalent of Ruby's Foreman) lets you define environment variables in [an "environment" (`.env`) file](https://honcho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using_procfiles.html#environment-files).

---

Finally, note that you *can* take advantage of the `PYTHONPATH` variable to store the settings in a completely different location (e.g. on a production server, storing them in `/etc/`). This allows for separating configuration from application files. You may or may not want that, it depends on how your app is structured.

Comment: To clarify, since the `settings.py` file is stored in `SiteName/settings.py` by default, if you place your alternate settings files in the same directory the line added to bin/activate should read `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="SiteName.test_settings"` Otherwise excellent answer!

Comment: by coincidence do you know a tutorial about how to doing this step by step, I am new to Django and don´t know where to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or PYTHONPATH

Comment: This solution does not seem to hold true for a conda env. There is no bin/activate in a conda env.

Comment: @PouyaYousefi: you absolutely don't _need_ to use virtualenv to use this answer. The answer really boils down to two steps: a) use separate settings files and b) use `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to pick the one you want to use. Modifying `bin/activate`  is one to do the latter (TBH, I no longer think this is a good idea anyway, so I took that out), but it's not the only one.

Comment: It is also useful If you are using Django in pycharm community edition and you need to run unit tests on both command line and pycharm community correctly.

Assume you created only one simple config file in myapp/settings.py in your source repository.
In that case, you'd set “DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings” in menu RUN/Edit Configuration/Environment variable to use it latter to run test cases.

Comment: With supervisor worked for me in the .ini file: 'environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.production_settings'

Comment: I am following this approach, create another `myapp.prod-settings` and on execution, pass the `--settings` arg like this `python manage.py runserver --settings=myapp.prod-settings` . This adds more flexibility as I see.

Answer (score 126):

By default use production settings, but create a file called `settings_dev.py` in the same folder as your `settings.py` file. Add overrides there, such as `DEBUG=True`.

On the computer that will be used for development, add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true
```

Or turn it on one time by prefixing your command:

```
DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true python manage.py runserver
```

At the bottom of your `settings.py` file, add the following.

```
# Override production variables if DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT env variable is true
if os.getenv('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT') == 'true':
    from settings_dev import *  # or specific overrides
```

(Note that importing `*` should generally be avoided in Python)

By default the production servers will not override anything. Done!

Compared to the other answers, this one is simpler because it doesn't require updating `PYTHONPATH`, or setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` which only allows you to work on one django project at a time.

Comment: how is this not the correct answer? SO is really a mess nowadays. Ty cs01

Comment: `if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT', 'true')` also works.  I mention this only because the above `is not true` method failed to import for me on Python 3.6.

Comment: @brt this is a bad idea: it will always use your `DEV` settings which will leak private data on a public server. You really just want to check that the `DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT` environment variable exists (i.e. `is not None`).

Comment: Thanks for the info, @cs01 .  I realized I did something wrong when I blew my site up with incorrect settings loading, but I wasn't sure why `settings_dev.py` was loading on the server.

Comment: @cs01 I would go so far as to make sure it exists and is truthy, by just dropping off the `is not None` check. Also `os.getenv` is the shorthand

Comment: Wouldn't this be better to go the other way around? Set the env variable in the production server as "DJANGO_PRODUCTION' or something. This would default to development for any new instance. until you set that variable obviously

Comment: IMO no. If development is the default, and it's accidentally deployed w/o the production env var, it leaks sensitive information that can be used by hackers. If you default to prod, worst case is you have to restart your server with the DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT environment variable.

Comment: i'd use `settings.py` as default and use `settings_prod.py` if `DJANGO_PROD` env is true. And put `settings_prod.py` in git ignore

Answer (score 61):

This is how I did it in 6 easy steps:

1. Create a folder inside your project directory and name it `settings`.

   *Project structure:*

   ```
   myproject/
          myapp1/
          myapp2/              
          myproject/
                 settings/
   ```
2. Create four python files inside `settings` directory namely `__init__.py`, `base.py`, `dev.py` and `prod.py`

   *Settings files:*

   ```
   settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        prod.py
        dev.py
   ```
3. Open `__init__.py` and add  following content:

   ***init**.py:*

   ```
   from .base import *
   # you need to set "myproject = 'prod'" as an environment variable
   # in your OS (on which your website is hosted)
   if os.environ['myproject'] == 'prod':
      from .prod import *
   else:
      from .dev import *
   ```
4. Open `base.py` and add all the common settings which will be used in both production as well as development:

   *base.py:*

   ```
   import os
   ...
   INSTALLED_APPS = [...]
   MIDDLEWARE = [...]
   TEMPLATES = [{...}]
   ...
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/path/')
   MEDIA_URL = '/path/'
   ```
5. Open `dev.py` and add development specific settings:

   *dev.py:*

   ```
   DEBUG = True
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
   ...
   ```
6. Open `prod.py` and add production specific settings:

   *prod.py:*

   ```
   DEBUG = False
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com']
   LOGGING = [...]
   ...
   ```

**Update**

As ANDRESMA suggested in comments. Update `BASE_DIR` in your `base.py` file to reflect your updated path by adding another `.parent` to the end. For example:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```

Comment: now the {% extends 'base.html' %} doesnt work. Did u change anything else?

Comment: Thanks for sharing!
I stumbled upon two things: I changed the _prod_ and _dev_ if-case, so when in doubt the prod settings will be used and I'm accessing _myproject_ variable via `os.environ.get('myproject')` ... so when the variable isn't set the code runs without error.

Comment: @cikatomo change the BASE_DIR var to get the project folder one level up

Comment: clean, simple, makes sense, easy enough for me, an idiot, to understand. thank you!

Comment: I had an issue importing from .base then importing from other settings files (step 3) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938105/django-separated-settings-by-environment-not-finding-variable-from-base-setti/72938660#72938660

Comment: haha! gpt4 tells me this answer.

Answer (score 39):

I usually have one settings file per environment, and a shared settings file:

```
/myproject/
  settings.production.py
  settings.development.py
  shared_settings.py
```

Each of my environment files has:

```
try:
    from shared_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This allows me to override shared settings if necessary (by adding the modifications below that stanza).

I then select which settings files to use by linking it in to settings.py:

```
ln -s settings.development.py settings.py
```

Comment: How do you deal with pep8 prohibition of `import *`? Do you disable that check? I've wrapped this import in an `exec()` but then I can't have conditionals on variables that aren't defined in this file, nor can I alter `INSTALLED_APPS` variable because it's "undefined"

Comment: We don't lint our settings files, because they aren't really code so much as they are configuration expressed in Python.

Answer (score 15):

I use the awesome [django-configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io), and all the settings are stored in my `settings.py`:

```
from configurations import Configuration

class Base(Configuration):
    # all the base settings here...
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    ...

class Develop(Base):
    # development settings here...
    DEBUG = True 
    ...

class Production(Base):
    # production settings here...
    DEBUG = False
```

To configure the Django project I just followed the [docs](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Additionally, you can add references to dotenv files in order to include them in a class, e.g., `DOTENV = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")` which will take the class name as the env file name.

Answer (score 12):

Create multiple `settings*.py` files, extrapolating the variables that need to change per environment. Then at the end of your master `settings.py` file:

```
try:
  from settings_dev import *
except ImportError:
  pass
```

You keep the separate `settings_*` files for each stage.

At the top of your `settings_dev.py` file, add this:

```
import sys
globals().update(vars(sys.modules['settings']))
```

To import variables that you need to modify.

This [wiki entry](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) has more ideas on how to split your settings.

Comment: Thanks Burham! When deploying the app, I would just need to remove the settings_dev file to see my deployment settings in action?

Comment: Yes, or replace the import with `settings_prod.py`

Comment: Editing the master settings.py file on a deployment means it'll clash with version control, though, so it's not necessarily the best way forward. I'd say that Thomas Orozco's option is best -- you can set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in your virtualenv postactivate script or in your gunicorn or mod_wsgi setup

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned, that you never add to source control the stage-specific files. I assumed that it was understood that you wouldn't push settings around that were specific to a stage of a project.

Comment: If you're using virtualenv, it will typically default to {{project_name}}.settings.  So 'settings' won't be a key in sys.modules.  It will be 'myproject.settings' (or whatever your project name is).  You can use `modname = "%s.settings" % ".".join(__name__.split('.')[:-1])` to get the full module name and then `globals().update(vars(sys.modules[modname]))`.  I find that works out nicely for me.  Of course forgoing the bit about programmatically determining the module name in favor of a string would probably work in most cases as well.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the approach we use :

- a `settings` module to split settings into multiple files for readability ;
- a `.env.json` file to store credentials and parameters that we want excluded from our git repository, or that are environment specific ;
- an `env.py` file to read the `.env.json` file

### Considering the following structure :

```
...
.env.json           # the file containing all specific credentials and parameters
.gitignore          # the .gitignore file to exclude `.env.json`
project_name/       # project dir (the one which django-admin.py creates)
  accounts/         # project's apps
    __init__.py
    ...
  ...
  env.py            # the file to load credentials
  settings/
    __init__.py     # main settings file
    database.py     # database conf
    storage.py      # storage conf
    ...
venv                # virtualenv
...
```

#### With `.env.json` like :

```
{
    "debug": false,
    "allowed_hosts": ["mydomain.com"],
    "django_secret_key": "my_very_long_secret_key",
    "db_password": "my_db_password",
    "db_name": "my_db_name",
    "db_user": "my_db_user",
    "db_host": "my_db_host",
}
```

#### And `project_name/env.py` :

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
import json
import os


def get_credentials():
    env_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    with open(os.path.join(env_file_dir, '.env.json'), 'r') as f:
        creds = json.loads(f.read())
    return creds


credentials = get_credentials()
```

#### We can have the following settings:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
# project_name/settings/__init__.py
from project_name.env import credentials
from project_name.settings.database import *
from project_name.settings.storage import *
...

SECRET_KEY = credentials.get('django_secret_key')

DEBUG = credentials.get('debug')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = credentials.get('allowed_hosts', [])

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    ...
]

if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar']

...

# project_name/settings/database.py
from project_name.env import credentials

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': credentials.get('db_name', ''),
        'USER': credentials.get('db_user', ''),
        'HOST': credentials.get('db_host', ''),
        'PASSWORD': credentials.get('db_password', ''),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

### the benefits of this solution are :

- **user specific credentials and configurations** for local development without modifying the git repository ;
- **environment specific configuration**, you can have for example three different environments with three different `.env.json` like dev, stagging and production ;
- **credentials are not in the repository**

I hope this helps, just let me know if you see any caveats with this solution.

Comment: assuming where `env` is to replace with `dev`, `prod` etc.? What goes in the old `settings.py` file? What's in `storage.py` and `database.py`?

Comment: Hi @dbinott, you can easily update the `env.py` file so that your can choose, with an environment variable, which file to load

Comment: For example :
conf = os.environ.get('CONF', '')
file_ = f".env.{conf}.json"

Comment: Why would you json as opposed to a native python datatype?

Answer (score 5):

Use `settings.py` for production. In the same directory create `settings_dev.py` for overrides.

```
# settings_dev.py

from .settings import * 

DEBUG = False
```

On a dev machine run your Django app with:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<your_app_name>.settings_dev python3 manage.py runserver
```

On a prod machine run as if you just had `settings.py` and nothing else.

**ADVANTAGES**

1. `settings.py` (used for production) is completely agnostic to the fact that any other environments even exist.
2. To see the difference between prod and dev you just look into a single location - `settings_dev.py`. No need to gather configurations scattered across `settings_prod.py`, `settings_dev.py` and `settings_shared.py`.
3. If someone adds a setting to your prod config after troubleshooting a production issue you can rest assured that it will appear in your dev config as well (unless explicitly overridden). Thus the divergence between different config files will be minimized.

Comment: Great additional advantage: One can simply **append** items to lists defined in `settings.py`. This is very useful with `INSTALLED_APPS`, among others.

Answer (score 4):

I use the folloring file structure:

```
project/
   ...
   settings/
   settings/common.py
   settings/local.py
   settings/prod.py
   settings/__init__.py -> local.py
```

So `__init__.py` is a link (ln in unix or mklink in windows) to `local.py` or can be to `prod.py` so the configuration is still in the `project.settings` module is clean and organized, and if you want to use a particular config you can use the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `project.settings.prod` if you need to run a command for production environment.

In the files `prod.py` and `local.py`:

```python
from .shared import *

DATABASE = {
    ...
}
```

and the `shared.py` file keeps as global without specific configs.

Answer (score 3):

building off cs01's answer:

if you're having problems with the environment variable, set its value to a string (e.g. I did `DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT="true"`).

I also changed cs01's file workflow as follows:

```
#settings.py
import os
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT') is not None:
    from settings_dev import * 
else:
    from settings_production import *
#settings_dev.py
development settings go here
#settings_production.py
production settings go here
```

This way, Django doesn't have to read through the entirety of a settings file before running the appropriate settings file. This solution comes in handy if your production file needs stuff that's only on your production server.

Note: in Python 3, imported files need to have a `.` appended (e.g. `from .settings_dev import *`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep 1 settings file, and your development operating system is different than your production operating system, you can put this at the bottom of your settings.py:

```
from sys import platform
if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
    # linux
    # some special setting here for when I'm on my prod server
elif platform == "darwin":
    # OS X
    # some special setting here for when I'm developing on my mac
elif platform == "win32":
    # Windows...
    # some special setting here for when I'm developing on my pc
```

Read more: [How do I check the operating system in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220108/how-do-i-check-the-operating-system-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You want to be able to switch settings, secretes, environment variables and others based on the git branch that you are in and relying on different settings file is okay but in an enterprise situation you would like to hide all your sensitive information from the repo. It is not a best security best practice to expose all the environment variables, secrets of all environments (develop, staging, production, qa etc.,) to all the developers. The following should achieve 2.

1. isolation of settings as per their environment of deployment
2. hide sensitive information from git repo

My run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# default environment
export DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT="develop"
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if [ $BRANCH == "main" ]; then
    export DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT="production"
elif [ $BRANCH == "release/"* ]; then
    export DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT="staging"
else
    # for all other branches (feature, support, hotfix etc.,)
    echo ''
fi

echo "
BRANCH: $BRANCH
ENVIRONMENT: $DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT
"
python3 myapp/manage.py makemigrations
python3 myapp/manage.py migrate --noinput
python3 myapp/manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

My vars.py (or secrets.py or whatever name) in the same folder as settings.py of django

```
vars = {
    'develop': {
        'environment': 'develop',
        'SECRET_KEY': 'mysecretkey',
        "DEBUG": "True"
        },
    'production': {
        'environment': 'production',
        'SECRET_KEY': 'mysecretkey',
        "DEBUG": "False"
        },
    'staging': {
        'environment': 'staging',
        'SECRET_KEY': 'mysecretkey',
        "DEBUG": "True"
        }
    }
```

then in settings.py just do the following

```
from . import vars # container environment specific vars
import os

DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv("DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT")  # declared in run.sh
envs = vars.vars[DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT] # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key 
used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = envs["SECRET_KEY"]

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = envs["DEBUG"]
```

Let developers have their own vars.py in their local machine but during deployment your cicd pipeline can insert the actual vars.py with actual valures or some script should insert it. If you are using gitlab cicd then you can store the entire vars.py as an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been answered, however a method which I use as combined with version control is the following:

Setup a env.py file in the same directory as settings on my local development environment that I also add to .gitignore:

env.py:

```
#!usr/bin/python

DJANGO_ENV = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'dev.mywebsite.com']
```

.gitignore:

```
mywebsite/env.py
```

settings.py:

```
if os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '/env.py'):
    #env.py is excluded using the .gitignore file - when moving to production we can automatically set debug mode to off:
    from env import *
else:
    DJANGO_ENV = False

DEBUG = DJANGO_ENV
```

I just find this works and is far more elegant - with env.py it is easy to see our local environment variables and we can handle all of this without multiple settings.py files or the likes. This methods allows for all sorts of local environment variables to be used that we wouldn't want set on our production server. Utilising the .gitignore via version control we are also keeping everything seamlessly integrated.

Comment: Simplest solution. One can also define everything in a `Config` class inside `env.py` file. Then instead of an `import *`, the module can be imported by `from env import Config`. This way you also don't need to use that if `os.path` check which makes this whole thing much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

For the problem of setting files, I choose to copy

```
Project
   |---__init__.py   [ write code to copy setting file from subdir to current dir]
   |---settings.py  (do not commit this file to git)
   |---setting1_dir
   |         |--  settings.py
   |---setting2_dir
   |         |--  settings.py
```

When you run django, __init__py will be ran. At this time , `settings.py in setting1_dir` will replace `settings.py in Project`.

How to choose different env?

- modify `__init__.py` directly.
- make a bash file to modify `__init__.py`.
- modify env in linux, and then let `__init__.py` read this variable.

---

Why use to this way?

Because I don't like so many files in the same directory, too many files will confuse other partners and not very well for IDE.(IDE cannot find what file we use)

If you do not want to see all these details, you can divide project into two part.

1. make your small tool like Spring Initializr, just for setup your project.(do sth like copy file)
2. your project code

Answer (score 0):

I'm using different app.yaml file to change configuration between environments in google cloud app engine.

You can use this to create a proxy connection in your terminal command:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:1433
```

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-admin-proxy#macos-64-bit

File: app.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
service: development
runtime: python37

env_variables:
  DJANGO_DB_HOST: '/cloudsql/myproject:myregion:myinstance'
  DJANGO_DEBUG: True

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a file named "production" in the working directory in production.

```
#settings.py
production = Path("production")
DEBUG = False

#if it's dev mode
if not production.is_file():
    INSTALLED_APPS +=[
       #apps_in_development_mode,
       #...
    ]
    DEBUG = True
    #other settings to override the default production settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to use the wsgi.py file for production (this file is created automatically when you create the django project). That file points to a settings file. So make a separate production settings file and reference it in your wsgi.py file.

Answer (score 0):

What we do here is to have an .ENV file for each environment. This file contains a lot of variables like `ENV=development`

The settings.py file is basically a bunch of os.environ.get(), like `ENV = os.environ.get('ENV')`

So when you need to access that you can do `ENV = settings.ENV`.

You would have to have a .env file for your production, testing, development.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution, with different environements for dev, test and prod

```
import socket

[...]

DEV_PC = 'PC059'
host_name = socket.gethostname()

if host_name == DEV_PC:
   #do something
   pass
elif [...]
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: This is bad for a few reason, but the most annoying one being that if you use more than one host for dev, you'd have to keep track of multiple DEV_PC_X variables, for no good reasons.