# How to exclude a file from a branch merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a repo with 2 branches; `master` and `dev`. There's this `config.json` file which is different for production and dev environments so I'd like to keep these files out of merge when I merge from `dev` to `master`.

Is there a way to do this permanently so whatever changes I make in `dev` branch and merge into `master`, it will never include the changes that is made into `config.json` file so I can keep their own versions of this file in both branches?

I could've used `.gitignore` but that would not include the file in their own branches when I do a `git commit` and `git push`.

Comment: In a word: don't. Find a different way to accomplish your goal, such as storing both, and choosing one based on environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore files in Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069179/how-to-ignore-files-in-git-merge)