# Django endpoint 500 error on calling endpoint

Tags: ajax, django, permissions, django-views, csrf

Im calling an endpoint in my template:

```
var postdata = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' }
$.post("reconcile/" + transaction_id, postdata);
```

Here is the view:

```
def reconcile_transaction(request, slug, id):
        society = get_object_or_404(Society, slug=slug)
        try:
            society.members.get(pk=request.user.id)
        except society.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        account = society.account
        transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=id)     
        print(transaction.get_stubbed_time)
```

I'm getting a 500 error at the print statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Turn off the DEBUG flag and look at the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter()` returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) (basically, a list of model instances). And, since there is no `get_stubbed_time` attribute on a `QuerySet` - you are getting `AttributeError` while trying to get `get_stubbed_time` attribute from a queryset. And, because of you are not running in the [DEBUG](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug) mode - you are seeing 500.

You need to use [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) instead:

```
transaction = Transaction.objects.get(id=id)     
print(transaction.get_stubbed_time)
```

Also, keep `DEBUG=True` in development - it helps a lot to quickly understand the root cause of errors. But, don't forget [to turn it off in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664244/django-how-to-manage-development-and-production-settings).

Hope that helps.