# when deploying an app, I'm creating new database correct?

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment

I almost finished writing my app in django, and checked out the steps to deployment. The thing I left to do is to switch my sqlite db to postgresql but do I need to do that in my deployment stage? won't I be installing postgresql db in deployment stage anyway since I will be using new system that digitalocean or aws provides? also for limited budget, I should be using digital ocean right?

Comment: I changed `development` to `deployment`, any objections?

Comment: aand it is not clear what you ask..

Comment: If you're looking for ways to handle production and development settings, that's not a simple Q&A. There's a lot of resources on the web for this, such as ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664244/django-how-to-manage-development-and-production-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clone project from local machine to VPS, like Amazon or Digital Ocean. You need to create enviroment like in local pc. Create new DB server, if you will use PostreSQL or MySQL, with SQLite you dont need it.
Also you need to delete old migrations from apps.

Comment: thank you the answer I was looking for, so simple answer to my question is yes right?

Comment: yes, if you want to use PostgreSQL, you need to install new SQL server in VPS

Comment: thank you, I;m getting createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory tho...I googled it and am trying to solve it right now