# Django separate settings files in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Following [multiple](https://medium.com/@ayarshabeer/django-best-practice-settings-file-for-multiple-environments-6d71c6966ee2) [articles](https://blog.apptension.com/2017/11/09/django-settings-for-multiple-environments/) [around](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html) the web, I've split my Django 1.11 `settings.py` file into multiple files, `base.py`, `local.py`, `staging.py`, `production.py`, in a `settings` folder.

The Django app runs in a Docker container.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
django:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: .env
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "mariadb:3306", "--", "/gunicorn.sh"]
```

In the `Dockerfile` I export the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as the `local` settings file (which in turn imports the `base.py` settings file).

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.6.4
RUN mkdir /app
ADD requirements/*.txt app/requirements/
RUN pip install -r mira/requirements/dev.txt
ADD . /app
RUN export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.local
RUN export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=dummy-secret-key
COPY ./docker/web/entrypoint.sh ./docker/web/gunicorn.sh ./docker/web/wait-for-it.sh ./docker/web/logging.conf ./scripts/setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh /gunicorn.sh /wait-for-it.sh /setup.sh
WORKDIR ./app
```

**settings/base.py**:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
```

**.env**:

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=FOOBAR
```

When I try to up the container, I get this error:

> The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

Comment: Agree: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292952) solved it for me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!