# Continuous deployment of a django server

Tags: django, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I would like to continuously deploy a django server. The command I run to deploy the server is

```
python manage.py runserver
```

However, this command runs as an infinite loop. Therefore, the associated job in the continuous deployment never ends. The problem is that I would like the server to be updated whenever some commit is done. But it won't work here because the next job associated with the commit won't start until the end of the first job.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: That is **not** a command that you should be running to deploy anything. That is for local development only.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Which command shoud I use then?

Comment: You should use a proper wsgi server - eg gunicorn, mod_wsgi, uwsgi. See [the deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read the documentation you provide and change the deployment process.

Comment: [Here is a guide of how to handle Django settings for local and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664244/django-how-to-manage-development-and-production-settings)

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally managed to solve my problem using apache and mod-wsgi. :)