# How to manage 2 settings files in Django by using Honco app?

Tags: django

My question is based on the following existing question:

[Django: How to manage development and production settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664244/django-how-to-manage-development-and-production-settings)

Basically if I want to have 2 or more settings.py files I could use  Honcho https://honcho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to do it .

Question is , in *.env  file what exact code should I write to use for  example following settings file:

“myproject.production_settings.py”

something like this?

```py
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.production_settings
```

or it should be different somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, tell us you tried it and what error you got.

Comment: Not yet. I am just prepearing my project to be deployed and whant to find out how to configure Honcho's .env file properly to load production setting when its time.

Comment: If your **production_settings.py** file is in the **myproject** directory (and there's an **__init__.py** file there) and your **myproject** directory is inside your `BASE_DIR`, then yes, this setting is correct. That's why I asked you to try. There's not reason to ask a question here if everything works :-)