# Django - separated settings by environment. Not finding variable from base settings

Tags: django, django-settings, django-3.2

I've split my django environment as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292952/4916945).

In `settings/base.py` I have `BASE_DIR` specified:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```

In `settings/__init__.py` I have:

```
from .base import *
env = os.environ['ENV']
...
if env == 'test':
  from .test import *
...
```

In `settings/test.py` I have `DATA_VOLUME_BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'scanned_images'`.

I expect that Django loads the settings module, imports `settings/base.py`, checks the environment ('test'), imports `settings/test.py` (which works) and the variable is available (which isn't). My stacktrace:

```
sid_test_web | Traceback (most recent call last):
sid_test_web |   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
sid_test_web |     main()
sid_test_web |   File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
sid_test_web |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_
sid_test_web |     utility.execute()
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
sid_test_web |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
sid_test_web |     self._setup(name)
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
sid_test_web |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
sid_test_web |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
sid_test_web |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
sid_test_web |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
sid_test_web |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
sid_test_web |   File "/code/my_project/settings/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
sid_test_web |     from .test import *
sid_test_web |   File "/code/my_project/settings/test.py", line 39, in <module>
sid_test_web |     DATA_VOLUME_BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'scanned_images'
sid_test_web | NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

How do I make `BASE_DIR` variable available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the `.base` setting in your test settings to make them available in `test.py`

```py
from .base import *
# ... your other test settings
```

The second thing is to choose which settings you like in the `__init__.py`.

```py
env = os.environ['ENV']
if env == 'test':
    from .test import *
else:
    from .base import *
```

Comment: Yes, this did it. The answer I linked said to import it how I did. Strange that it's so highly rated.

Comment: In the post you linked they didn’t used any variables defined in the base.py one their specific settings files. That’s the difference. But we always use the pattern like in my answer. This allow us to reuse defined settings and just overwrite the ones we need to adjust.