# Django - separating prod and dev settings - delete original settings.py?

Tags: django

I'm following the below answer on separating development and production Django settings file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292952/15166930

1. After separating, would I delete the original settings.py file?
2. Is this the common practice on separating the files? I see multiple methods on that SO post.
3. Also, per the SO answer, I'm to update the BASE_DIR in my base.py file to

> BASE_DIR = Path(**file**).resolve().parent.parent.parent

right now it's as below:

```
settings.py
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Just want to confirm because the two are so different.. thx (Django 2.1.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of methods for having different settings in development and production.

If you choose to follow the method you have linked, then yes, you would remove your original `settings.py` file and replace it with a `settings` directory that contains
`base.py`, `dev.py` and `prod.py`; with `base.py` containing the common settings and the other files containing the contextual settings (whether you are either in development or production).

Also, is there a critical reason you are using Django 2.1.7? It has a number of [known vulnerabilities](https://security.snyk.io/package/pip/django/2.1.7).

Comment: Appreciate it! I was following Corey Schafer's Django youtube tutorial and just followed his exact steps. Thanks for sharing that, I'm going to update it to a more stable version now. Big help

Answer (score 1):

You can use different settings using the [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) library, you create .env file from where you pull your settings.

Another solution is to have a settings_local.py file from where you pull your settings as well, and adjusting it according to your environment.

Edit : I agree with the first answer stating that using django 2 today is a bad idea, many many things changed since then and if you really want to follow a tutorial, I'd recommend something more up to date, like William S. Vincent books, "Django for Beginners: Build websites with Python and Django", there are 4.X books already.
I highly recommend his books for beginners, as it takes a good project oriented approach.