# How to install and uninstall any browser on an EC2 instance using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, browser, amazon-ec2

I am super new to python and AWS as well. I want to install and uninstall web browsers like Chrome/ Firefox/ IE etc as per the requirement on EC2 instances using Python. I am yet not sure whether "BOTO" can be useful here and I am using Python 2.7.9. Any suggestions / guidelines / overview / tutorial are appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: @Mahendran - For scripting I can use Windows or Linux .But the OS on which the browser should be installed is selected dynamically.

Comment: Suggestion. First you need to find in [which os](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220141/3049065) you are going to install. Get the user input for which browser to install and based on the os selection you need to fetch the respected execution file. For firefox you can get it from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/). Check related install option based on os. For linux you can able to create a bash script and make it [run on python script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13745648/3049065).

Comment: why would you want to install a browser in a server? why would you do it from python? why would you consider doing it using boto?

Answer (score 0):

Boto allows you to make API calls to AWS services like EC2 and S3. It's not relevant to installing web browsers on EC2 instances.

You mentioned IE so I'm assuming that your EC2 instances are Windows, not Linux. Python is not likely to be the best way to install and uninstall Windows applications. You might want to host the installation binaries somewhere and then use a CMD script to do silent installs/uninstalls (Firefox example [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Installer:Command_Line_Arguments)) or even look at a Windows package manager like [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages).

Comment: @jarmod- Thanks for helping. I derived that I am now supposed to use Chef tool for that purpose.