# Python limit usage to Linux only

Tags: python

I have a program I'm thinking through right now and doing tons of investigating on.  One of the stipulations with the program is that I want it so it can only run on Linux.  I DO NOT want the program to be usable on Windows or Apple...Linux only.  I have my reasons.

I know you can use certain modules(tkinter...root.mainloop()), ie, that will cause a program to not run in Windows if you leave certain things out.  Is there a way you can accomplish the same task without using any particular module...just 'base code'?

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on

Comment: Do you intend to distribute the source for your script, or will you be packaging it into some kind of binary distribution?

Comment: Given the nature of the program...binary distribution.  Once the program is written and compiled I will destroy the source code.  Quite sensitive coding.

Comment: I would note that if you really intend to "destroy the source code", you might reconsider your choice of Python. Most methods of bundling up a Python script into an executable simply embed the script text in an archive along with a Python interpreter - the script is still there for somebody willing to poke around a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just *test* for Linux:

```
import platform
import sys


if platform.system() != 'Linux':
    sys.stderr('Linux required\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize there was a REAL nice shortcut for finding out the operating system.  Thanks.