# tkinter - setting icon

Tags: python, tkinter

### Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

1) root.iconbitmap("/home/inspiron/git_code/mp/images/m_player.ico")

2) root.iconbitmap("m_player.ico")

3) root.iconbitmap(r"m_player.ico")

root.mainloop()
```

---

All three lines are showing error:
eg. error for case 2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music.py", line 5, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap(r"m_player.ico")
  File "/home/inspiron/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1868, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "m_player.ico" not defined
```

---

I wrote all the three lines just for asking, in the code I used them separately. I saw answers of same question asked, but none of them solved this issue. Also the file `m_player.ico` is in the same folder in which `music.py` is present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter command "iconbitmap"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973246/python-tkinter-command-iconbitmap)

Comment: No improvements, I am using ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS , I did convert .png to .ico and also to .xbm , but it is showing same error.

Comment: On **ubuntu** try this Answer: [iconbitmap error in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860521/7414759)

Comment: Thanks , but it solved the issue partially, using    root.iconbitmap("@filename.xbm") shows no error , But while running , no icon is shown in the tkinter window.

Comment: For me, with `LXDE`, this Answer works: [`gui.call('wm', 'iconphoto', gui._w, logo)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723710/7414759)

Comment: Wow !! It worked. Thanks again....