# is there a way to know whether robot runs on Windows or Linux

Tags: robotframework

I run robot, sometimes in Linux and sometimes in Windows.
Is there a simple way to identify on which OS robot runs, so it could apply different behavior?

Comment: You could write keywords around platform library that return platform name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to return python's platform information.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${system}=    Evaluate    platform.system()    platform
    log to console    \nI am running on ${system}
```

For more information about asking python about what system it is running on, see this question: [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)