# Depending on the OS, define different methods

Tags: python

Although Python doesn't have the C pre-processor, I wonder, what's a way to declare methods and variables depending on the OS?
Something like:

```
class C1:

#if defined(WINDOWS)
        self.var1 = 1

        def method1(....):
            pass

#elif defined(LINUX)
        self.var2 = 1

        def method2(....):
            pass

#endif
```

**My question isn't how to detect the platform only**. But how to define different methods and variables depending on **it also**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check what OS am I running on in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/how-to-check-what-os-am-i-running-on-in-python)

Comment: You can use the output of `platform.system()` in the conditional statements you wrote above, like so. `if platform.system() == 'Linux': #do this`

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the current platform as follows

```
import platform
platform.system()
```

The output for me is

```
'Linux'
```