# How can I avoid using path name in my Python scripts?

Tags: python

In my Python scripts, I write the specific path name. It will not work if I were to use it on another computer or folder.

ex: `df = pd.read_csv('C:/VerySpecificNameForDocuments/test.csv', 'wb')`

I have seen the use of: `%/...`

How can I re-write this to be usable in other computers/directories?

Comment: I don't think we have enough to answer this. What are your requirements? Will this file be provided by the user? Is there a working directory you can depend on being present? Can you provide a command-line option that tells the program where to find stuff? We don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am looking to run my scripts on other computers and give them to others to use and I imagine their directories are different. For example: a script that organizes files will need to adapt to the person's directories. Yes, the files will be read from the user's computer.

Comment: If you have to handle different operating systems and filespecs you'll have to build than in as well. This is probably well out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `hardcode` a `path` on your scripts, `environment variables` are your friends, in python you can access them using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ), i.e.:

```
import os
# %USERPROFILE% environment variable  + "/documents" creates the path to `My documents` folder on windows systems
csv_file =  '{}\\documents\\file.csv'.format(os.environ['USERPROFILE'])
# C:\Users\Administrador\documents\file.csv
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, 'wb')
```

---

Other interesting windows `environment variables`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['HOMEPATH']
'\\Users\\Administrador'
>>> os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']
'C:'
>>> os.environ['WINDIR']
'C:\\WINDOWS'
>>> os.environ['APPDATA']
'C:\\Users\\Administrador\\AppData\\Roaming'
>>>
```

---

PS:
If you need to support multiple OS's (linux, mac, windows), you may want to implement a simple [OS detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/797495) function and deal with each system individually.

Comment: I am assuming they'd need admin privileges... Thanks Pedro!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do if you wanted is have a tkinter file selection window come up for the user. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog #You might not need this line, sometimes I run into an error if I don't have it

tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

The "file" variable will have the full path with the file name.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that I was missing an import when I typed this up yesterday. I've fixed it so it should work now if you couldn't run it before