# Opening file when path has "\v" in it

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that receives string of path and in the example I have, it has the "\v" in it , how do I solve it ?

```
getting error : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\x0baction.txt'

def foo(file1,file):
   file2=open(file2,"r")

def main():
 foo("C:\work.txt", "C:\vaction.txt")
```

Comment: change the backslashes to forward slashes: `foo("C:/work.txt", "C:/vaction.txt")` or a pass a raw string `foo(r"C:\work.txt", r"C:\vaction.txt")` or escape the backslashes: `foo("C:\\work.txt", "C:\\vaction.txt")`

Comment: this question has been asked before, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746407/getting-os-error-when-passing-string-to-pathlib-path-in-windows/54746518#54746518

Comment: i thought there would be a better way to change the string inside the function i'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Either use raw strins `r"C:\new.txt"` or use double backslash `"C:\\new.txt"`. I prefer using second method, because it is also used in system.

PS. I suppose you are on Windows

Comment: i think using the "C:\\" would be the better way , but i thought there could be another way

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
import re
escaped = re.escape(yourString)
```

Best