# Pandas: skip lines containing a certain string when reading a file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big text file (300000000 rows) but it is full of undesired data, which I would like to remove. Those data are the one containing the string "0000e".

I tried:

```
f=pd.read_csv('File.txt', skiprows=139, header=None, index_col=False)
f=f.iloc[:,0]
f1=f[f.str.contains("0000e")==False]
```

and

```
f=pd.read_csv('file.txt', skiprows=139, header=None, index_col=False, chunksize=50)
dfs = pd.concat([x[x[0].str.endswith('000e')==False] for x in f])
```

but it is rather long, is there a faster way to skip some lines containing a certain string? Perhaps with na_values?

Comment: What are your intentions with these rows? You could also use the `memory_map` option to improve performance in the loading stage and possibly other stages/.

Comment: To speed things up have you tried just reading the .txt file into a file object (not via pandas in this case) and then save each line to a string list.  Excluding the lines that contain '000e' as you add them to the list.  Could be a tuple even.

Comment: Then afterwords, if your file needs more analysis, you can save it to a dataframe and proceed.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer your first attempt more as it is definitely more readable atop the fact that your second line has x's and I don't know what they refer to.

That said, using `memory_map=True` will boost the performance <sub>as noted in the docs</sub>, you can also gain an extra advantage by removing the second line and accessing the column in the same line you create the `df`. Lastly, replacing the check `...==False` with `~...` may provide some benefit. as `~` is a logical `not` but you need to filter out all the `NaN` values or you get an error. Luckily `Series.str.contains` accepts and `na` attribute appliying the given function to `NaN` values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('File.txt', memory_map=True, header=None, index_col=False).iloc[:,0]
df1 = df[~df.str.contains("test", na=False)]
#if you want to also skip NaN rows use the below statement
df1 = df[~df.str.contains("test", na=False)].dropna()
```

Alternatively, **doing this using `csv` is much faster** even if you decide to load it into pandas afterwards. I don't know what your data looks like but I tested these with a `csv` file cointaining 3 columns and 100 rows and I got roughly 9x better performance. This probably won't correlate to you're results but this is definitely the method I would choose if I were you.

```
from csv import reader

filter = '0000e' #so we aren't making a new string every iteration
with open('File.txt', 'r') as f:
  df = pd.DataFrame(first for first, *_ in reader(f) if filter not in first)
  #if you want to skip NaN rows
  ...(first for first, *_ in reader(f) if not first and filter not in first)
  #take note this also skips empty strings, use if first is not None for only skipping NaN values
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried method 2 and it works faster. I have now a DataFrame of 1999048 rows and facing a new speed issue for the processing of my data. I'll post a new question.Thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to a linux or mac os system, you can do this in a pre-processing step that is probably much faster with `grep -v`, which returns all lines that do **not** match

```
grep -v 0000e File.txt > small_file.txt
```

on windows (I think) it's [`findstring /v`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490907(v=technet.10))

```
findstring /v File.txt > small_file.txt
```

---

you can call the os command from inside your python code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/2327328)

and if you want to make it able to handle multiple os'es, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/2327328)