# Find Windows OS Version/Edition in Sikuli

Tags: jython, sikuli

I work in both a Windows 7 and 10 environment and the file locations don't match up. I'm trying to write a Sikuli script that will go in, check which Windows version is being used (7 or 10) and then proceed. I attempted to use:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
print "windows10"
else: 
print "windows7"
```

but I'm honestly stuck, what's the easiest way to go about this? Any information will help! Attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on) as well but my results are java or Java. Maybe I'm not implementing it right?

```
import os
print os.name 
# result = java
import platform
print platform.system()
#result = Java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since with SikuliX you are running inside the Java environment, you have to ask the Java environment, where it is running on ;-)

try this:

```
import java.lang.System as JS
print JS.getProperty("os.name");
print JS.getProperty("os.version");
```

on my Windows 10 it tells me

```
Windows 10
10.0
```

All the best. RaiMan from SikuliX ;-)

Comment: Worked just as I needed! Thanks!