# pytest command-line argument: default value OS dependent?

Tags: python, pytest

A [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) takes a command line argument whose default value is OS dependant.

This works only on OS X where the value is `file.dylib`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--filename', type=str, default='file.dylib')
```

On Windows this value should be `file.dll`, on Linux `libfile.so`.

Is there a way to make the default value work on all OSes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
def get_lib_name():
    libnames = {'Windows': 'file.dll', 'Darwin': 'file.dylib', 'Linux': 'file.so'}

    osname = platform.system()

    if osname in libnames:
        return libnames[osname]
    else:
        raise OSError('OS not supported.')
```

Call `get_lib_name()` from parser:

```
parser.addoption('--filename', type=str, default=get_lib_name() )
```