# Is it possible to push to Gitlab with the Python API?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, ipython, gitlab-api

I am just messing around, but I have a blank project in Gitlab. I have a Python script (well, ipython notebook). I would like the Python script to simply push any files in "C:/users/files" to the Gitlab project.

I cannot find any instruction on how to do this from the API webpage here - https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/commits.html.

It looks to me like it is impossible to do this, but surely it is.

Comment: Why not just execute bash commands from python? Something like cd C:/Users/files && git pull origin master && git add * && git commit -m "whatever" && git push origin master

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás good idea; but ideally I'd like it to run in windows and Linux if possible.

Comment: A workaround would be a conditional depending on the OS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/what-os-am-i-running-on

Answer (score 4):

Push is not possible with API but only possible with Git protocol. You can use [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/) (depends on `git` as it runs `git` under the hood) or [dulwich](https://dulwich.io/) (doesn't depends on `git` as it implements Git protocol in Python).