# How to receive OS version for Mac? For Python 3.7

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

First of all, sorry for this stupid question.

I want to receive OS version for Mac by python command. Awaiting for output like this:

MacOS Sierra (mine) **version 10.12.6**

Version is the main goal.

I already tried to use platform and os modules, but not succeed.

Thank you!

EDIT:

It can be executable by os.system('sw_vers')

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/what-os-am-i-running-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sw_vers` command will gives you this information,

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G3020
```

Since you are interested in getting version, do string formatting.

```
>>> import commands
>>> output = commands.getoutput('sw_vers')
>>> version = output.split('\n')[1].split(':\t')[1]
>>> version
'10.14.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with builtin libraries:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.mac_ver()
('10.15.4', ('', '', ''), 'x86_64')
```