# How to find which os we are using without importing the os module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across this interesting question my friend asked me. He told that he found a way to know which os we are on without importing the `os` module. Can any of you help me with the same?

Comment: For example: `import platform; platform.uname()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this could work:

```
if r"\" in __file__: print("Windows") 
else: print("Unix variant")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import platform
print(platform.system())
print(platform.release())
print(platform.version())
```

Comment: `platform` imports `os`, so maybe this is not what the OP wanted.