# What can we use to distinguish beetween linux and macos AppVeyor builds?

Tags: python, unit-testing, appveyor

AppVeyor provides build worker images for windows, linux and macos to run unit tests.

So we can use the same appveyor.yml to control builds running on both these OS.

[We can distinguish between windows and linux platforms by using few possibilities, as variables ($isLinux, $isWindows, APPVEYOR_YML_DISABLE_PS_LINUX) or prefix commands](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/getting-started-with-appveyor-for-linux/) ( sh:, cmd:).

What can we use to distinguish beetween linux and macos ?

I need a solution in command line. I had thought of solution as using python -c "import platform; platform.system()", but how can I get the result in this case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash:

```sh
platform=$(uname -s)
if [[ $platform == Darwin ]]; then
    echo "it's macOS"
elif [[ $platform == Linux ]]; then
    echo "it's Linux"
else
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Python: What OS am I running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on)

```py
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows' # for Linux it prints 'Linux', Mac it prints `'Darwin'
```

Comment: I need to a solution in command Line. I had thought of this type of solution using python -c "import platform; platform.system()", But how can I get the result in this case ?