# How do I ensure that a dependency only gets installed on Windows with Poetry?

Tags: python, windows, python-poetry, package-management

I'm developing a Python application using Poetry as project management tool, and I have a dependency which I only want to install on Windows. [PEP 425](https://peps.python.org/pep-0425/) says the following on the matter:

> The platform tag is simply distutils.util.get_platform() with all hyphens - and periods . replaced with underscore _.

If I run `distutils.util.get_platform()` on a 64-bit Windows host, I get this:

```
>>> import distutils
distutils.utils.get_platform()
'win-amd64'
```

So far so good. I now have the platform tag for 64-bit Windows. The issue is that I don't want to specifically specify 64-bit Windows but rather Windows in general as the dependency should be installed on all variants of Windows. For Linux, this tag is just "linux", and macOS is "darwin", but I can't seem to find any examples for Windows.

What value should I pass to `$ poetry add --platform` to ensure that a dependency only gets installed on Windows? Or, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you wanted `platform.system()` instead? Or, `os.name`, but the values that returns are a little "weirder". See [How to identify which OS Python is running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/how-to-identify-which-os-python-is-running-on) for the full run-down.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, sure sounds like it. Thanks. The only problem is that it doesn't seem like Poetry likes it since it doesn't install the dependency if I set the `platform` to `windows` or set `markers` to `sys_platform == 'windows'`, but I guess what you say answers what I actually asked regardless of whether it solves my particular problems.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the question to reflect my issue better

Comment: Note that `platform.system()` is not `windows` on Windows , but `Windows` with a capital `W`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's the same with Linux (capital first letter), but I've been using `sys_platform != 'linux'` just fine. Additionally, `sys_platform == 'Windows'` does not seem to work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: That's not a "but", that's literally the right string comparison. Capital `L` on `Linux` =) What's `sys_platform` though? Because if you're pulling it from Python's own `platform` module, that should absolutely be `Windows` if you're on Windows. If it's not, _that's a bug_ and you should report it O_o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256061/discussion-between-newbyte-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different possibilities, the one thing that worked was this:

```
$ poetry add --platform=win32
```

I don't know why it wants `win32` specifically, but this makes Poetry install the dependency even on 64-bit Windows, while also not attempting to install it on Linux.